# SQL Server Reporting Services Round() function

Tags: sql-server, database

there is some bizarre thing happening with my report generated in SQL Server Reporting Services and I hope I am not being too stupid. I use the Round function to get integers. Sometimes a 4.5 will round to 4 and a 5.5 will round to 6. Is this because of the rounding method? I am using this:

```
Round(Fields!GroupAverageAssessment.Value,0)
```

How can I make a regular rounding (4.5 to 5, 3.5 to 4, 6.5 to 7 and so on...)

Thanks

Comment: What datatype is your original field? A float datatype might look like it is 4.5 but really be 4.49999999999 or something and the 5.5 might really be 5.500000000000001

Comment: If *sometimes* in "sometimes a 4.5 will round to 4 and a 5.5 will round to 6" is actually *every time*, then it is using Banker's rounding.

Comment: Thanks, the field is defined as Double, so that should not be the problem. I will try awayfromzero rounding.

Comment: @Marcos: double has exactly the same problem as float. It can be slightly inaccurate. This is probably not your problem here judging from your description, but it could be, and you certainly should investigate it if other solutions fail.

Comment: Awayfromzero worked for me. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Marcos:  See this for more background http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It sounds like [round to even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), also known as Banker's rounding.

The other option is "away from zero", which is what you want:

```
Round(4.5, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: Updated answer - just realised that AwayFromZero is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I was puzzeled because I read the documentation and when I tried MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero the code was underlined as wrong. Anyway, I will give it a try...

Comment: Awayfromzero worked for me, but the red-underlined was still there. Where do I place the import System? Thank you for the help.

Comment: using System, sorry... or just be explicit: System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Answer (score 2):

Use the `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` option:

```
Round([calculated number], [num decimal places], MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know.