# SSRS round down

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having a problem as I have a requirement to round DOWN a number in SSRS. For example I have a value of `£466.535` which I would expect to round up to `£466.54`. Is there a way to round the value to `£466.53`.

Thanks

Comment: @DannyBeckett, thanks for this, my only fear that I may get a `.00` from this though

Comment: Check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202579/sql-server-reporting-services-round-function