# SSRS - Visual Studio round issue

Tags: vba, visual-studio, reporting-services

I hope this question is not so stupid.
We have an expression column which need to be rounded to 3 decimals. Like, if the expression's result = 0.1805, then round to 0.181, if the expression's result = 0.1804, then round to 0.180. At the same time, if the expression's result = 0 , then show 0.

The thing is that, right now, round(0.1805,3)=0.18 instead of 0.181, which I don't know why. If I change the column's properties to show 3 decimal, then it will show the expression round(0.1805,3) as 0.181, but it would also show 0 as 0.000 which we don't want to. Does anyone has any idea that why the round(0.1805,3)=0.18 here instead of 0.181, while round(0.1806,3)=0.181 which is correct. Thanks a lot!
[image]

Comment: The combination of `vba` and `visual-studio-code` as tags makes no sense. Which language are you talking about? Can you show the piece of code you use?

Comment: [I think the Round function is doing `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2202614/3585500)  [Round function.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding)

Comment: Hi, I'm creating a SSRS report using Visual Studio. In the report, I need to keep 3 decimals for a column calculated from an expression. This round function is from the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because *Round* performs Banker's Rounding.

You may have to use Format (or ToString) which does true 4/5 rounding.

```
Format(0.1805, "0.000")
-> 0.181
```

If not only for display, convert that to decimal or currency.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Never realize that we could use format like this, thanks a lot!