# Math.Round for decimal in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Here is a sample code

```
decimal num1=390, num2=60, result;
result=num1/num2; // here I get 6.5
result=Math.Round(result,0);
```

the final value of result should be **7** but, I am getting **6**. Why such a behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check third parameter [MidpointRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx).

By default used MidpointRounding.ToEven, so

```
Math.Round(result,0); // 6.0 
//or
Math.Round(result,0, MidpointRounding.ToEven); // 6.0 

//But:
Math.Round(result,0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero); // 7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx):

> If the fractional component of d is
>   halfway between two integers, one of
>   which is even and the other odd, the
>   even number is returned.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of rounding is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx

Example:

```
//       11.1 --> 11
//       11.2 --> 11
//       11.3 --> 11
//       11.4 --> 11
//       11.5 --> 11
//       11.6 --> 12
```

Answer (score 1):

decimal.Math.Round uses MidpointRounding.ToEven as default.

Meaning if the one's digit is odd, it is changed to an even digit. Otherwise, it is left unchanged. This behavior follows IEEE Standard 754, section 4. It is sometimes called rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding. It minimizes rounding errors that result from consistently rounding a midpoint value in a single direction.

Comment: Se the doc here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx and here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It must be the same reason as why

```
      Math.Round(6.5, 0);
```

similarly yields 6 rather than 7. It all comes down to the MSDN documentation [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx) which exemplify

```
  Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(3.45, 1)); //Returns 3.4.
  Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(4.35, 1)); // Returns 4.4
```

in [another MDSN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) is states

> The integer nearest parameter d. If the fractional component of d is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Decimal instead of an integral type.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.Ceiling Method().
decimal num1=390, num2=60, result;
result=Math.Ceiling(num1/num2);

Comment: Not the same as rounding, 5.4 -> 6 instead of 5.