# C# Math.Round(value / 2). value is decimal. function not working for one specific number 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking to round decimal, 0.1 to 0.4 round down and 0.5 to 0.9 round up
tried these but for some reason if value is 4.5 it rounds to 4 and not 5
all other values work fine.
3.5=4.0 , 5.5=6.0  but 4.5 =4.0 expecting 5.0

```
Math.Round(value / 2)
Math.Round(Math.Round(value / 2),0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Comment: Any time a method isn't doing what you expect, first [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_).

Comment: You have left out the most important fact: **what is the type of `value`**?

Comment: Also, why on your second line are you rounding, and then rounding the already-rounded value? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Math.Round Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890085/c-sharp-math-round-error)

Answer (score 5):

Your first line is using the default type of rounding (known as banker's rounding). Your second line *almost* gets what you want, but you don't need to include two calls to `Math.Round()`.

For what you're wanting, it should probably look like this:

```
Math.Round((value / 2), 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
// e.g. 3.5 => 4, 4.5 => 5, 5.5 => 6, etc.
```

Read more about banker's rounding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default), and read more about `Math.Round()` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Math_Round_System_Double_).