# C# Rounding MidpointRounding.ToEven vs MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Tags: c#, rounding-error

In C# Is there any difference in the accuracy of the two decimal rounding strategies `MidpointRounding.ToEven` and `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`? I mean do both ensure an even distribution amongst the numbers that are rounded to, or is one rounding strategy over representing   the rounded numbers compared to the other?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default should clear things up :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From the .NET Documentation page on `Math.Round`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round#midpoint-values-and-rounding-conventions

By default, `Math.Round` uses `MidpointRounding.ToEven`. Most people are not familiar with "rounding to even" as the alternative, "rounding away from zero" is more commonly taught in school. .NET defaults to "Rounding to even" as it is statistically superior because it doesn't share the tendency of "rounding away from zero" to round up slightly more often than it rounds down (assuming the numbers being rounded tend to be positive.)

Depending on the data set, symmetric arithmetic rounding can introduce a major bias, since it always rounds midpoint values upward. To take a simple example, suppose that we want to determine the mean of three values, 1.5, 2.5, and 3.5, but that we want to first round them to the nearest integer before calculating their mean. Note that the true mean of these values is is 2.5. Using symmetric arithmetic rounding, these values change to 2, 3, and 4, and their mean is 3. Using bankers rounding, these values change to 2, 2, and 4, and their mean is 2.67. Because the latter rounding method is much closer to the true mean of the three values, it provides the least loss of data.

Comment: But then the question is... why would you round them first to integers if you know want to calculate their mean? :)

Answer (score 14):

If your value is **123.45** then

> 123.5  <-- MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero
>   123.4  <-- MidpointRounding.ToEven

Answer (score 0):

```
1) .NET using MidpointRounding.ToEven for default method of Math.Round
2) MidpointRounding.ToEven will round off to upper limit if fraction value grater then 5
3) MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero will round off to upper limit if fraction value equal and grater then 5
4) for e.g. if we want to Round off 12.1250 in 2 digit with 2 fraction
Math.Round(12.1250,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 12.12 (fraction value in 50)
Math.Round(12.1250,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) => 12.13

Math.Round(12.1251,2,MidpointRounding.ToEven) => 12.13 (fraction value in 51)
Math.Round(12.1251,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) => 12.13
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).