# Proper way to do rounding for currency conversion in Paypal?

Tags: c#, paypal, decimal, currency, rounding

I'm building an ecommerce site integrated with paypal.

We take multiple currencies, so I want to make sure that (for accounting reasons) i'm correctly performing any math for currency conversion.

After multiplying the currency conversion * the original currency, I always end up with lots of trailing numbers after the decimal point.

Is there a standard way to do this?  Should I truncate or round? Do I need to round multiple times in case rounding the 1/1000 decimal will affect rounding the 1/100 decimal?

Should I be doing something like:

```
Math.Round(Math.Round(x, 3), 2)
```

I've been having trouble finding good information about how this is done (hopefully US and Europe are the same).

Comment: Could you use some sort of formatting based on the number of decimal positions that you are getting..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `Math.Round(x, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Comment: This isn't the "bankers rounding" mentioned above... any thoughts?

Comment: I suppose since you're doing the currency conversion this could arguably be better that you guys would ALWAYS get some fraction of a cent that wouldn't have existed.

Comment: Well... this was the CLOSEST to the answer.  After speaking with the accountant, supposedly the trick is to always round up from 5 when calculating your taxes/VAT.  That way, you are always sure/safe that you paid your taxes. Slightly different topic from original post - but my question is answered.

Comment: It's the way I was taught rounding in school and, as I never (unnecessarily) use rounded values in intermediate calculations I'm not worried about a bias in my rounding, I can't bring myself to use the default rounding method in .NET.  Note also that .ToString("0.00") uses this method, as does display rounding in Excel.

Comment: This only works correctly for currencies with 2 decimals right of the decimal point, line EUR and USD. There are many currencies which are different, like Algeria, Iraq, Kuwait and a few other Middle Eastern nations, using 3 decimals, Bitcoin uses 8. Chtiwi Malek's answer works for any currency.

Answer (score 3):

I would assume you should just be able to directly use Math.Round as .NET uses [Bankers Rounding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Just remember to always make rounding be the absolute very last thing you do to not introduce rounding errors.

In a currency system like this, I would also store the real unrounded values as decimals additionally for future problem solving purposes.

Answer (score 3):

if your site has multiple currencies then use this to correctly round decimals according to the current user's currency and culture :

```
int currencyDecs = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits;
decimal roundedDecimalPrice = Math.Round(decimalPrice, currencyDecs, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```