# Converting a double to an int in C#

Tags: c#, int, double

In our code we have a double that we need to convert to an int.

```
double score = 8.6;
int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(score);
int i2 = (int)score;
```

Can anyone explain me why `i1 != i2`?

The result that I get is that: `i1 = 9` and `i2 = 8`.

Comment: `Math.Truncate(score)` is more explicitly express intention than `(int)score`

Comment: But Math.Truncate returns a double or decimal, not an int

Answer (score 236, accepted):

Because [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx) rounds:

> Return Value: rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value
>   is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned;
>   that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

...while the cast [truncates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx):

> When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type, the
>   value is truncated.

**Update:** See Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment below for additional differences (which however do not come into play if `score` is a real number as is the case here).

Comment: Your link actually explains it best, and its not as simple as round vs truncate: Type: System.Int32
value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit signed integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is converted to 6.

Comment: @ericosg: Yeah, that would mask the difference if `score` were `8.5` instead of `8.6`. I updated the answer to include the quotes. Thanks for the input.

Comment: And if `score` is `NaN` or an infinity or finite but outside the range of `Int32`, then `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception. Cast will return an `int`, but you won'y know which one (in my implementation it's `Int32.MinValue`) because you're in `unchecked` context. (Should you be in `checked` context, the cast will throw an exception as well in these cases.)

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Thanks for the input, I updated the answer to mention this too.

Comment: Nice. But I think the `Double` type number `10000000000.6` (ten billion point six) is a "real" number. Using a cast to `int` on that will give a strange result (unless you're in `checked` context, but you probably aren't).

Answer (score 20):

Casting will ignore anything after the decimal point, so 8.6 becomes 8.

`Convert.ToInt32(8.6)` is the safe way to ensure your double gets rounded to the nearest integer, in this case 9.

Comment: Bonus question - what happens of if the value of the *double* is too large to push into the *int*? I.e. if it's higher than *int.MAX_VAL*?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Throws an exception _Value was either too large or too small for an Int32._

Answer (score 12):

you can round your double and cast ist:

```
(int)Math.Round(myDouble);
```

Comment: the question was now **how** to make `i1 == i2`. The question was about **why** they are not equal. Downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

In the provided example your decimal is **8.6**. Had it been 8.5 or 9.5, the statement **i1 == i2**  might have been true. Infact it would have been true for 8.5, and false for 9.5.

**Explanation:**

Regardless of the decimal part, the second statement, `int i2 = (int)score` will discard the decimal part and simply return you the integer part. Quite dangerous thing to do, as data loss might occur.

Now, for the first statement, two things can happen. If the decimal part is 5, that is, it is half way through, a decision is to be made. Do we round up or down? In C#, the Convert class implements banker's rounding. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default) answer for deeper explanation. Simply put, if the number is even, round down, if the number is odd, round up.

E.g. Consider:

```
        double score = 8.5;
        int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(score); // 8
        int i2 = (int)score;             // 8

        score += 1;
        i1 = Convert.ToInt32(score);     // 10
        i2 = (int)score;                 // 9
```

Answer (score 1):

ToInt32 rounds.  Casting to int just throws away the non-integer component.