# Why Convert.ToInt32(1.0/0.00004) != (Int32)(1.0/0.00004)

Tags: c#, math, .net-4.0, casting, clr

Why this code  http://ideone.com/YRcICG

```
void Main()
{   
    double a = 0.00004;
    Int32 castToInt = (Int32)(1.0/a);
    Int32 convertToInt = Convert.ToInt32(1.0/a);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1:F9} {2:F9}", castToInt == convertToInt, castToInt, convertToInt);

    Console.WriteLine((((int)(1.0/(1.0/25000))) == 24999));
}
```

results in

> False 24999,000000000 25000,000000000
>   True

in context of CLR/C# implementation

Comment: `0.00004` is not representable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick lies in the way the double is represented so (1.0/a) will be represented in the following way:

(1.0/a) = 24999.99999999999636202119290828704833984375.

When you use cast you get only the first part of this number, while the convert Method works in a different way, here is the code for the Convert method:

```
public static int ToInt32(double value)
{
    if (value >= 0.0)
    {
        if (value < 2147483647.5)
        {
            int num = (int)value;
            double num2 = value - (double)num;
            if (num2 > 0.5 || (num2 == 0.5 && (num & 1) != 0))
            {
                num++;
            }
            return num;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (value >= -2147483648.5)
        {
            int num3 = (int)value;
            double num4 = value - (double)num3;
            if (num4 < -0.5 || (num4 == -0.5 && (num3 & 1) != 0))
            {
                num3--;
            }
            return num3;
        }
    }
    throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_Int32"));
}
```

As you can see there is an if statement that checks the difference between casted value and original double, in your example it is:

```
int num = (int)value;
double num2 = value - (double)num;

24999.99999999999636202119290828704833984375 - 24999 > 0.5
```

, hence you get the increment.

Comment: This answers the question.

Answer (score 3):

In your calculation, the answer to `1.0/0.00004` is getting converted to a value very slightly smaller than 2500, because floating-point numbers can't precisely represent all possible values. Given that,

**Why do the two integers have different values?**

Casting a double to an int [truncates the value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx), so everything after the decimal point is discarded.

`Convert.ToInt32` on a double [rounds to the nearest integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffdk7eyz.aspx).

**Why are floating point numbers imprecise?**

See the excellent article linked in another answer: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

**How can I represent values precisely?**

You could use a decimal type rather than double. There are pros and cons to doing this, see [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Answer (score 1):

Cast trunk the floating number

> (Int32)41.548 == 41

Convert round the number (feature?)

> Convert.ToInt32(41.548) == 42

Comment: It is not a feature, it is fully documented behavior (see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10754283/1166450))

Comment: That's not explain why ((int)(1.0/(1.0/25000))) == 24999

Comment: @diimdeep, because `1.0 / 0.0004 == 24999.999999999996`. I've edited my previous comment, see related question.

Comment: What ? Actually (1.0 / 0.00004) == 25000

Comment: @diimdeep, set a breakpoint after `double r = 1.0 / 0.0004;` and look at `r` value. You will be surprised :).

Comment: Debugger can be more buggy than Console.WriteLine don't you think ?

Comment: No. Try it: `double r = 1.0 / 0.00004; Console.WriteLine(r.ToString("R"));`

Comment: You both now that you are using different denominators right?

Comment: @diimdeep : 1/0.0004 == 2500 but 1/0.00004 != 25000 -- a whole order of magnitude tends to affect things. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Floating point math is not exact. Simple values like 0.2 cannot be precisely represented using binary floating point numbers, and the limited precision of floating point numbers means that slight changes in the order of operations can change the result. A must read:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

> The IEEE standard divides exceptions into 5 classes: overflow, underflow, division by zero, invalid operation and inexact. There is a separate status flag for each class of exception. The meaning of the first three exceptions is self-evident. Invalid operation covers the situations listed in TABLE D-3, and any comparison that involves a NaN.

Comment: Just a question, but does that document cover the difference between casting and converting, because it's a rather long document.

Comment: Can you provide more details about CLR implementation that is different campare one to another ?

Comment: Have you read the question? Because I am not sure the code is about precision in general. It's about the difference in `Convert`