# Float to String Conversion

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I want to convert float value to string.

Below is the code which i am using for the conversion.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s =string.Format("{0:G}", value);                
            Console.Write(s);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

and it outputs as `2.5`

But my problem is i want to get the value as `2.50` because i want to compare it with original value later in my project.

so please suggest me if there are any ways to do it?

Comment: Why are you comparing numbers by their string representation and not their value?

Comment: That is requirement in my project. I have to compare the string(which i read from a  file) if they are converted back properly.@Corak

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using `{0:N2}` to format to two decimal places.

```
string.Format("{0:N2}", 2.50)
```

For 3 decimal places:

```
string.Format("{0:N3}", 2.50)
```

And so on.

You can also store the value in a string this way without worrying about precision and then convert your value where you are testing for comparison as string:

```
string strDecimalVal = Convert.ToString( 2.5000001);
```

Comment: This way is great. But if i give 2.500 it should also output as 2.500

Comment: See my edit. I have already mentioned how you can keep increasing the decimal width - :)

Comment: yes i got that, but if i give 2.50 i want the output to be same. Not 2.500 if i specify {0:N3}

Comment: Then in that case do not format just convert to string like this: `Convert.ToString( 2.5000001)` and store in your string variable

Comment: @NomeshGajare as a float, `2.50` is exactly the same as `2.500` or `2.5`. If you want to difference them you should store them as string literals.
Edit: See [@heinzi 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19044089/1192381).

Comment: Heinzi's answer is correct but floating point comparisons are not guaranteed to work in all case for eg if its Nan.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027762/why-convert-toint321-0-0-00004-int321-0-0-00004

Answer (score 5):

> because i want to compare it with original value later in my project.

...then you will need to store the number of decimal places the original value had. Once the value is a float, this information is lost. **The float representations of `2.5`, `2.50` and `2.500` are exactly the same.**

So, basically, you have the following possibilities (in order of preference):

- Don't do a string comparison between the old and the new value. Convert both values to float and then compare them (with a margin of error since [floats are not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3874627/87698)).
- Store the number of decimal places of the old value and then use `myFloat.ToString("F" + numDecimals.ToString())` to convert it to  a string.
- Store the value as a string instead of a float. Obviously, you won't be able to do math on that value.

Alternatively, if you do not insist on using floats, `decimals` might suit your purpose: The *do* store the number of significant digits:

```
decimal x = Decimal.Parse("2.50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal y = Decimal.Parse("2.500", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(x.ToString()); // prints 2.50
Console.WriteLine(y.ToString()); // prints 2.500
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:F2}", 2.50);
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", 2.50);
Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}", 2.50);
```

Version 1 and 2 are almost similar, but 3 is different. 3 will include number separators when number is large.

For example the following outputs `454,542.50`

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}", 454542.50);
```

More on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)