# Integer Conversion in C#

Tags: c#, int

```
        string[] strArray = new string[10] { "21.65", "30.90", "20.42", "10.00", "14.87", "72.19", "36.00", "45.11", "18.66", "22.22" };
        float temp = 0.0f;
        Int32 resConvert = 0;
        Int32 resCast = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
        {
            float.TryParse(strArray[i], out temp);
            resConvert = Convert.ToInt32(temp * 100);
            resCast = (Int32)(temp * 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Convert: " + resConvert + " ExplCast: " + resCast);
        }
```

Ans :

```
   Convert: 2165 ExplCast: 2164   // ??
   Convert: 3090 ExplCast: 3089   // ??
   Convert: 2042 ExplCast: 2042
   Convert: 1000 ExplCast: 1000
   Convert: 1487 ExplCast: 1486   //??
   Convert: 7219 ExplCast: 7219
   Convert: 3600 ExplCast: 3600
   Convert: 4511 ExplCast: 4511
   Convert: 1866 ExplCast: 1865   //??
   Convert: 2222 ExplCast: 2221   //??
```

Why the value differs sometimes while doing Explicit Cast , but not always.
Any reason ?

Comment: try Int64 at the place of Int32

Comment: @Rana: What is the issue with Int32 ? Any Specific reason ?

Comment: R.S. Rana: That's nonsense for values that small.

Comment: I wonder if you tried int32.tryparse(temp *100) if the values would also differ

Comment: Eric : TryParse allow strings only..                                                      int ival =0;
bool b = Int32.TryParse("21.65", out ival); //false                    And the conversion fails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To take one example, 21.65 in `float` format is actually represented by a number like 21.6499999. The `Convert.ToInt32` rounds the number to the nearest integer, yielding 21.65, while the explicit cast `(Int32)` just truncates (rounding toward zero), so you get 21.64.

If you want the floating point numbers to be represented in the computer the same way they look printed out, use `decimal` instead of `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gabe. But why it is not in all scenario.       For eg.                                                                   Convert: 4511 ExplCast: 4511  // OK
 Convert: 2222 ExplCast: 2221   //??

Comment: 22.22 cannot be encoded exactly as a floating point number. When you multiply by 100, you end up with a value something like 2221.999999

Comment: Round-to-even is the default `.Round` behavior in .NET isn't it? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default

Comment: @MSK (and others): It is very interesting to notice that if you try this on a 64-bit machine, with exactly these numbers, and if you compile your code with the **x64** "Solution Platform" setting, then this behavior goes away! In that case the compiler really does the multiplication with 64-bit numbers ("double precision", not "single"), and only after that converts to `float`/`Single`. Of course, the same kind of behavior will also arise with double precision if you choose your numbers differently. But here's an example where a program does something else when compiled for x64.

Answer (score 4):

`Convert.ToInt32` [rounds to the nearest integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8.aspx), the direct cast just truncates the number.

So, if you, due to floating point imprecision, have a value of `2165.99999whatever` instead of `2165.0`, the direct cast truncates all after the floating point, while `Convert.ToInt32` rounds to the nearest integer.

Example:
`22.22f * 100.0f` results in something like `2221.99993133544921875`.
So `Convert.ToInt32` will round it **up** to the expected value `2222`, while the cast will truncate it to `2221`.

`45.11f * 100.0f` on the other hand results in about `4511.00006103515625`,
which `Convert.ToInt32` rounds **down**, which results in `4511`, the same result as when casting directly.

Answer (score 2):

Following from Botz3000 answer, Relevent sections from MSDN:

[Convert.ToInt32 Method (Single)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/303w38b8)

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 value, rounded to the nearest 32-bit
>   signed integer. If value is halfway between two whole numbers, the
>   even number is returned; that is, 4.5 is converted to 4, and 5.5 is
>   converted to 6.

[Explicit Numeric Conversions Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288039%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> •When you convert from a double or float value to an integral type,
>   the value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If
>   the resulting integral value is outside the range of the destination
>   value, the result depends on the overflow checking context. In a
>   checked context, an OverflowException is thrown, while in an unchecked
>   context, the result is an unspecified value of the destination type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the problem is caused by inaccuracies with floating point precision, specifically using a `float`. You will find the issue disappears when using a `decimal`. There is a really good answer on the differences between decimal and double (and float) here: [decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

Comment: Hi again @Kane. This is misleading. Try this: (int)((1m/3m)*300m) (hint, it's not 100). Decimals might be more appropriate for some kinds of numbers, binary floats for others, but both are susceptible to this kind of problem. (but in the case where decimal strings are parsed, decimal would indeed be the right way to go)

Answer (score 1):

Calling Convert.ToInt32 is like calling:

`(int) Math.Round(floatValue, 0);`

Direct Casting is like calling

`(int) Math.Floor(float);`

Floor always gives you a value less than or equal to the value you supply in the argument. Floating point representations are not "precise". So 21.65 is probably represented as 21.649999 or similar since there is not enough precision.

So:
21.65 *100 = 2164.9999
Flooring this value should give you an integer which is smaller than or equal to 2164.9 ... ie: 2164

Rounding 2164.99 on the other hand would give you: 2165

You can see the effect here:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(21.65f*100));  //2165
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(21.65f*100));  //2164
```

Using doubles instead of float's (more precision, but still not infinite):

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(21.65d*100));  //2165
Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(21.65d*100));  //2165
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why it is not in all scenario

Comment: Ah, it's because of the way floating point numbers are stored in memory. Some numbers can be precisely represented, some numbers cannot be. Loads of gory details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision

Comment: Try this page: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=050049046054053
The best representation of 21.65 = 2.16499996185302734375E1
The best representation of 20.42 = 2.042E3 (nice and precise!)