# "Convert.ToInt32" Behave Differently For Odd and Even Numbers

Tags: c#

In a C# Application

```
Convert.ToInt32(22.5) = 22
Convert.ToInt32(23.5) = 24
```

Odd and Even Numbers Converting Differently! Why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431793/why-does-convert-toint32-round-to-the-nearest-even-number-instead-of-nearest

Comment: Do you mean beyond that it's documented that way?