# What is wrong with Math.Round() in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

I have encountered a weird case in Math.Round function in VB.Net

```
Math.Round((32.625), 2)
```

***Result : 32.62***

```
Math.Round((32.635), 2)
```

***Result : 32.64***

I need **32.63** but the function is working in different logic in these cases.

I can get the decimal part and make what I want doing something on it. But isn't this too weird, one is rounding to higher, one is rounding to lower.

So how can I get **32.63** from **32.625** without messing with decimal part ? (as the natural logic of Maths)

Comment: my guess it has to do with the representation of floating point numbers, so 63.625 might be actually 63.6249999...

Comment: But I'm writing it just there "63.625". so it can not be "63.624999" am I wrong ?

Comment: You are, unfortunately, wrong - the number looks like 32.625 but internally it is stored as an Float-value, which is imprecise. Use a decimal datatype for high precision, but slow performance.

Comment: @ChristianSauer - In this case, 63.625 is exactly representable as a float.  The problem is the rounding method as pointed out by Steven in his answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Math.Round` uses *banker's rounding* by default.  You can change that by specifying a different `MidPointRounding` option.  From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx#Midpoint):

**Rounding away from zero**

> Midpoint values are rounded to the next number away from zero. For
>   example, 3.75 rounds to 3.8, 3.85 rounds to 3.9, -3.75 rounds to -3.8,
>   and -3.85 rounds to -3.9. This form of rounding is represented by the
>   MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero enumeration member. Rounding away from
>   zero is the most widely known form of rounding.

**Rounding to nearest, or banker's rounding**

> Midpoint values are rounded to the nearest even number. For example,
>   both 3.75 and 3.85 round to 3.8, and both -3.75 and -3.85 round to
>   -3.8. This form of rounding is represented by the MidpointRounding.ToEven enumeration member.
>
> Rounding to nearest is the standard form of rounding used in financial
>   and statistical operations. It conforms to IEEE Standard 754, section
>   4. When used in multiple rounding operations, it reduces the rounding error that is caused by consistently rounding midpoint values in a
>   single direction. In some cases, this rounding error can be
>   significant.

So, what you want is:

```
Math.Round(32.625, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Math.Round(32.635, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

As others have mentioned, if precision is important, you should be using `Decimal` variables rather than floating point types.  For instance:

```
Math.Round(32.625D, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
Math.Round(32.635D, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: I think the story is a bit more complicated than described in this answer. Note that thanks to the usual what-you-see-is-not-what-you-get nature of binary floating-point, `32.635` is _not_ a midpoint value, so it's unaffected by the midpoint rounding rule. (In Python 3, `round(32.635, 2)` gives (the nearest float to) `32.63`, even though Python _is_ using banker's rounding, and the `round` operation is correctly rounded.) It appears that VB.Net is (deliberately or not) _not_ doing correct rounding in this case: if it were, it would have given `32.63` regardless of midpoint rounding mode.

Answer (score 4):

Try this (from memory):

`Math.Round((32.635), 2, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Dim d As Decimal = 3.625
    Dim r As Decimal = Math.Ceiling(d * 100D) / 100D
    MsgBox(r)
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: sorry, I edited my answer. I need to get 32.63 from 32.625  without messing with decimal part ?

Comment: Okay, that changes things.

Comment: Edited my answer to suit your needs based on that information. Hope it helps. I used the msgbox for testing, you can take it out. Sorry. It's a short way to do it. In fact you should make a function out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Hers a quick function you can add to simplify your life and make it so you don't have to type so much all the time.

```
 Private Function roundd(dec As Decimal)
    Dim d As Decimal = dec
    Dim r As Decimal = Math.Ceiling(d * 100D) / 100D
    Return r
End Function
```

Add this to your application then use the function

```
roundd(3.624)
```

or whatever you need.

to display the result - example

```
msgbox(roundd(3.625))
```

This will display a messagebox with 3.63

```
Textbox1.text = roundd(3.625)
```

this will set textbox1.text - 3.63 etc. etc. 
So if you need to round more then one number, it won't be so tedious and you can save alot of typing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can't using floats which is what numbers like  32.625 is treated as in VB.Net. (There is also the issue of Banker's rounding as mention by @StevenDoggart - you are probably going to have to deal with both issues.)

The issue is that the number stored is not exactly what is entered because these numbers do not into a fixed binary representation e.g. 32.625 is stored as 32.62499997 and 32.635 as 32.63500001.
The only way to be exact is to store the numbers as the type Decimal

```
DIM num as Decimal
num = ToDecimal("32.625")
```

Comment: In VB.NET, you can simply use the `D` suffix to specify a `Decimal` literal (e.g. `32.625D`)

Comment: How are you getting the value 32.62499997 from 32.625?  32.625 should be exactly representable as a float or double.  The value I get (using code from Jon Skeet's site) for **32.635** is 63.63499999999999801048033987171947956085205078125.

Comment: CPUs differ in the way of representing/processing/converting floats - why it is a bad idea to store money as a float datatype.  Try it on many different processors, and you'll see the difference (double is also a float and you'll get spurious results - these datatypes are from the olden days of computing and should probably be avoided unless speed is of the essence)