# How do I round to an arbitrary number of decimals (i.e., from 3.32 to 3.30) in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, rounding

If I want to round 3.32 to 3.30 and 3.38 to 3.40, how can I do that?

I tried `math.round()`, but I couldn't do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you try this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835001/what-is-wrong-with-math-round-in-vb-net)?

Comment: You have to stand on your head to call that "round up".  Yes, use Math.Round().

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [Math.Round Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in VB.NET

> Rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of
>   fractional digits.

Try like this:

```
Math.Round(3.32, 1)
```

or this:

```
Math.Round(3.32, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) 
Math.Round(3.38, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: @HansPassant:- I think OP has missed to specify the significant number of digits which he wants or may be MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero. But it is just a guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of significant figures in the Math.Round routine (overload). I'm used to C# but the VB.NET syntax should be something like:

```
Math.Round(3.44, 1)
```

See "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa340228(v=vs.71).aspx" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous solutions, to get two-digit correct decimal values, use this:

```
FormatNumber((Math.Round(3.32, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)), 2) 
' Returns 3.30

FormatNumber((Math.Round(3.38, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)), 2) 
' Returns 3.40
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Math.Round(3.32, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)  ' Returns 3.3
Math.Round(3.38, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)  ' Returns 3.4
```

The first parameter is the number to round.  The second parameter specifies how many digits to round to after the decimal point.  The third parameter specifies that you want to use standard away-from-zero rounding rather than bankers rounding).