# VB.NET - DataGridView substring cell for Number(10,2)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, substring, variable-length

I have a DataGridView with a column where the user can insert double. I have to control the cell value before i insert in my database because the table have a number(10,2) datatype for this field.

**My current code :**

```
Dim length As Integer = Nothing    
Dim row As Integer = DTG.CurrentCell.RowIndex
Dim column As Integer = DTG.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex()

With DTG(row).Cells(column)
    length = Len(.Value)
    If Not IsNothing(.Value) Then
            If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                    .Value = 0
            End If

            If length > 10 Then
                    .Value = .Value.SubString(0, 10)
                    If .Value.Contains(".") Then
                        .Value = .Value.SubString(0, 9)
                    End If
            End If
    End If
End With
```

The length method is not appropriate here, because if my cell contains ".", the length increases.

**Examples :**

```
1234567891 => length = 10 => insert : 1234567891

123456789.1 => length = 11 => insert : 123456789
```

In the 2nd case, i need to insert `123456789.1`

Can someone advise me ? Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally decided to work with the cell value.

```
If .Value > 99999999.99 Then
    .Value = Convert.ToDouble(.Value.SubString(0, 8))
End If
```

I changed the style format to "N2", so the user can't write more than 2 decimals :

```
.ValueType = GetType(Double)
.Style.Format = "N2"
```

I also found another way to do this, i could format my column like a masked textbox. I'll try this solution later.

**EDIT :**
The previous answer is pretty bad but it had helped me for a while. I found a better way to handle my problem. I created a function that check the number of digits before the decimal, and if the length is higher than 8, its return `False` :

```
Public Function numberDigitsBeforeDecimal(ByVal montant As Double) As Boolean
    Dim beforeDigit As String = montant.ToString.Substring(0, montant.ToString.IndexOf("."))

    If beforeDigit.Length > 8 Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.Value.IndexOf(".")` to get the number of digits before the decimal separator (<= 10).

Comment: Is there something similar working with the .value including digits after the decimal separator ?

Comment: The number of digits after separator : `Len(.Value) - .Value.IndexOf(".") - 1`. Of course, this only works if `.Value.Contains(".")` is true.

Comment: I think there is a better way to do this, i'll continue to search.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, a database field with a datatype of `number(10,2)` means that it can carry a maximum value of `99999999.99`, using this you might change your code to look like

```
Dim dbMaxNum As Decimal = 99999999.99

With DTG(row).Cells(column)
    If Not IsNothing(.Value) Then
        If Not IsNumeric(.Value) Then 
            .Value = 0
        Else
            .Value = Math.Min( _
                        dbMaxNum, _
                        Math.Round(CDec(.Value), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
        End If
    End If
End With
```

Where we first round `.Value` to two decimal places and then we choose the minimum between the result and the maximum your database field can hold (`99999999.99`)

The option `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` is to prevent unexpected rounding results, for example `32.625` rounding to `32.62` (an issue that was brought up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835001/what-is-wrong-with-math-round-in-vb-net)).

Comment: read number datatype part on [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm) documentation.

7,456,123.89 with NUMBER(9,2) is stored as 7456123.89

Comment: I'm not seeing that I'm incorrect about anything that I've said, what are you implying? The documentation says that a datatype `NUMBER(10,2)` is capable of holding a max of 10 digits but 2 of them are reserved for the decimal part (which means the _number part_ cannot be over 8 digits long) so the maximum number that can be held is `99999999.99`. In both your examples, you're attempting to insert numbers that are greater than `99999999.99`.