# VB.net Rounding issue

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the below formula to try and get an interest rate but it is sometimes coming up a penny short

`dim float as decimal = Math.ROUND((((Convert.ToDecimal(35000000.00) * Convert.ToDecimal(0.020625)) / 360) * 3), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

This is equaling 6015.62...if i do the math on a calculator I get 6015.625 which I would then want to round up to 6015.63...how can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with Math.Round() in VB.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14835001/what-is-wrong-with-math-round-in-vb-net)

Comment: Your formula returns 6015.6249999999999999999999999, not 6015.625. You end up with 35000000 * 0.020625 / 360 = 2005.2083333333333333333333333 then you have * 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a rounding problem. Your formula returns 6015.6249999999999999999999999, not 6015.625.

> 35000000.00 * 0.020625 = 721875
>   721875 / 360 = 2005.208333333333
>   2005.208333333333 * 3 = 6015.624999999999

If you change your formula to

> (35000000.00 * 0.020625) / (360 / 3)

Then you get

> 35000000.00 * 0.020625 = 721875
>   360 / 3 = 120
>   721875 / 120 = 6015.625

Even if you change the order you'll get what you want.

> 35000000.00 * 0.020625 * 3 / 360

Calculators sometime do fancy things. But the compiler does one step at a time and doesn't look at what was done previously.

Comment: Ah I see...is there a way to round 6015.6249999999999999999999999 to 6015.63 then? as that would round to 6015.625 and then round to 6015.63?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a way to do that because it could change other result. I would just change the order of operation like do division last, or simplified 360/3.

Comment: Changed the formula to `Math.Round((((Convert.ToDecimal(Amount) * Convert.ToDecimal(Rate))) * (DaysProcessed / 360)), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Comment: @ertuu85 - updated my answer (you can also change from decimal to double - less precise).