# VB.Net Why does Math.Round round 5 to the nearest even number, and what can I do about it?

Tags: .net, vb.net

Why is Math.Round(0.125, 2) rounding to 0.12?

```
Dim foo As Decimal
foo = Math.Round(0.125, 2)
```

foo is now 0.12 but it should b 0.13

I heard it's because some standard in .Net rounds to the nearest even number, but that's just bad math. 12.5 will round down to 12, but 13.5 will round up to 14.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: FYI, this is known as "banker's rounding".

Comment: It is banker's rounding.  Use the Round() overload that takes a MidpointRounding argument to change it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `Math.Round(decimal)` method:

> If the fractional component of *d* is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, the even number is returned.

The same logic applies to the `Math.Round(decimal, int)` overload. Notice:

```
Math.Round(0.125, 2) // 0.12
Math.Round(0.135, 2) // 0.14
Math.Round(0.145, 2) // 0.14
```

It's not 'bad math'; it's a common rounding strategy known as 'round-to-even'. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even):

> This variant of the round-to-nearest method is also called **unbiased rounding**, **convergent rounding**, **statistician's rounding**, **Dutch rounding**, **Gaussian rounding**, **odd-even rounding**, **bankers' rounding** or **broken rounding**, and is widely used in bookkeeping.
>
> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 computing functions and operators.

If you want finer control over how it rounds, you can specify a `MidpointRounding` parameter

```
Math.Round(0.125, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // 0.13
```

Comment: Ah, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero does the trick. I learn something new every day. Thanks!