# Round function not working properly

Tags: vbscript

I tried to round off value using VBscript

here is my code

```
sql = "select lastcode from " & session("gasbook") & ".acccode where account='" _
      & Trim(rsgrn.fields("stockcode")) & "'"
response.write sql
rs.Open sql, cn
if err.number<>0 then
    cn.rollbacktrans
    call HandleError(err.number,err.description,err.source)
        Response.End
else
    if (rs.EOF and rs.BOF) then
        cn.RollbackTrans
        Response.Write "GAS Code doesn't exist in " & session("gasbook")
        Response.End
    else
        If clng(rs.Fields("lastcode")) <> 0 Then
            cn.RollbackTrans
            Response.Write "Stock Account must be control account in " _
              & session ("gasbook")
            Response.End
        End If
    end if
end if
dim tmp
tmp = rsgrn.Fields("amount")
response.write tmp
response.write round(tmp)
```

`tmp` has value **2984.5**, but when I apply `round` on `tmp` it convert into **2984** instead of **2984.5**.

Comment: Actually, you may find it has the _actual_ value of something like `2984.499999999314159` hence why it's rounding down.

Comment: to value is exact **2984.5**

Comment: Is your variable a floating point or decimal number? Use VarType(yourvar) to find out.

Comment: Do you mean it's rounding to 2984 instead of 2985?

Comment: Please don't shout. We're not deaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is rounded to 2948 because the .Net framework follows the [Bankers Rounding algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Roundings_to_nearest) off of the IEEE 754 standard. It is not a question of if the number was rounded, it is rounded to the nearest even number due to standards.

Evidence: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default). and [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

So, the round function is working perfectly to the IEEE Standards.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se6f2zfx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). Without the optional second parameter `numdecimalplaces`, the `Round` function returns an integer:

> *numdecimalplaces*
>
> Optional. Number indicating how many places to the right of the decimal are included in the rounding. If omitted, integers are returned by the Round function.

Change the line

```
response.write round(tmp)
```

to

```
response.write round(tmp, 1)
```

if you want the value rounded to one decimal.