# Why does Round produce a different result than Application.Round

Tags: vba, excel

I am finding that the VBA Round function returns the wrong result. I found a working alternative which is to use the `Application.Round` instead.

Why doesn't the VBA `Round` function work as expected?

```
Sub roundingResults()
    Range("A1") = 123456.705
    Debug.Print "Approach #1 " & Round(Range("A1").Value, 2)
    Debug.Print "Approach #2 " & Application.Round(Range("A1").Value, 2)    
End Sub
```

Output

```
Approach #1 123456.7
Approach #2 123456.71
```

Comment: See [HERE](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/58972.html) for a better explanation, but  the gist is that there are two ways to round number ending in 5.  The 1st approach uses the toward even.  So if you changed the number to `123456.715` both would return the `123456.72`.  The second appraoch uses the 5 as the deliminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no entirely correct answer for how to round.  The differences have to do with how to handle values that fall exactly on the midpoint.  `Application.Round` will always round up in that instance.  e.g.  0.5 will round to 1.0.  VBA.Round will tie break to the closest even number

```
1.5-->2   
2.5-->2  
3.5-->4
```

and so forth.  This is one way of several ways of reducing the bias inherent in always rounding up.

Also, if interested, there is a fairly extensive discussion of Rounding in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding)

Comment: Beat me by 20 seconds.

Comment: @ScottCraner :-)  Rounding is an interesting topic for me.  There are many different ways of tiebreaking in addition to those used in the Excel and VBA functions.

Comment: Additional info. VBA is using banker's rounding http://www.xbeat.net/vbspeed/i_BankersRounding.htm.  Same method in .net http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default