# How Excel VBA rounds Doubles to Integers?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to understand the type of errors that could happen when a wrong type of variable is declared in VBA.

This is the code I am using:

```
Sub testTypes()

Dim test1 As Integer
test1 = 0.5

Debug.Print test1

End Sub
```

I tried to use Double number types on purpose to see how VBA will round them (up or down) to make them an Integer, given that the number ends on .5

I got puzzling results:

```
5.567 --> 6
5.5 --> 6
4.5 --> 4
3.5 --> 4
2.5 --> 2
1.5 --> 2
0.5 --> 0
```

Could anyone explain how Excel determines whether it will round up or down?

Comment: It rounds towards the even number.  It is called "Banker's Rounding".

Comment: @Scott never knew that, thanks for the tip! @Sandra if you want to force rounding up or down, you can use `WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(test1, 0)` (or `RoundDown` with the same syntax).

Comment: Hey @ScottCraner thanks for naming the problem! I think this definition I found makes it even more clear: 

"It rounds up when the digit before the 5 is odd. If it's even it rounds down.

Example
1.1235 rounds to 1.124
1.1225 rounds to 1.122

Comment: It was an IEEE 754 at play here. Check the answer by Ostemar in [Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default). Also this [MS article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/26/bankers-rounding/) back in 2003! Imagine the sum of a billion of these round off errors can have to actual sum without this standard!

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid so called banker's rounding (= midpoint value 5 always rounds to the nearest even number ) you can use

- (1) `WorkSheetFunction.Round`
- (2) a user defined function.

Banker's rounding is a standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations in order to minimize significant rounding errors over multiple rounding operations by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction.

**(1) Example using the WorksheetFunction `Round()`**

```
Sub RoundWithWorkSheetFunction()
' Purpose: avoid so called bankers' rounding in VBA (5 always rounds even)
With WorksheetFunction
    Debug.Print "WorksheetFunction.Round(3.5, 0)=" & .Round(3.5, 0), ":| VBA rounds to " & Round(3.5, 0)
    Debug.Print "WorksheetFunction.Round(4.5, 0)=" & .Round(4.5, 0), ":| VBA rounds to " & Round(4.5, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

**(2) An alternative to the worksheet function (avoiding bankers' rounding):**

```
Function roundIt(ByVal d As Double, ByVal nDigits As Integer) As Double
' Purpose: avoid so called bankers' rounding in VBA (5 always rounds even)
If nDigits > 0 Then
   ' if continental european colon instead of point separartor
   ' roundIt= val(Replace(Format(d, "0." & String(nDigits, "0")), ",", "."))
     roundIt = Val(Format(d, "0." & String(nDigits, "0")))
Else
   ' if continental european colon instead of point separartor
   ' roundIt =  val(Replace(Format(d / (10 ^ nDigits), "0."), ",", "."))
   roundIt = Val(Format(d / (10 ^ nDigits), "0."))
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Sandra, it will round up or down depending if it is an even or odd number. If it is an even number, it will be round down. Otherwise, it will round up.