# Rounding off any cell with numbers using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, automation, rounding

I have a non fixed set of data that may vary in rows and columns.

I intend to use VBA to search the whole dataset and round off all cells with numbers to a specified decimal place. (or rounded to nearest 100s or 10s too)

I have the following code:

```
Sub roundthissheet()
Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

rng = Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

For Each cell In rng.cells
    If cell.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Value = Round(cell.Value, -2)
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

However, my if statement does not seem to run at all and I encounter the error message "Object variable or With block variable not set"

How shall I proceed with regards to this error?

Comment: ActiveCell should probably be ActiveSheet.

Comment: For the error you mention, note that objects need to be `Set`.  So you should have `Set rng = Range("A1",...)`  Of course, there are other errors in your code as noted in some of the answers below.

Comment: Note that VBA's `Round` function uses so called *bankers' rounding* which might return unwanted results; it's a standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations in order to minimize significant rounding errors over multiple rounding operations by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction - c.f. [How Excel VBA rounds doubles...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850958/how-excel-vba-rounds-doubles-to-integers/48042374#48042374) An alternative would be to use `WorkSheetFunction.Round` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the number format then try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to round it then you do not need to loop through all cells. Use `SpecialCells` to loop through only cells which have number

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            For Each aCell In rng
                aCell.Value = Round(aCell.Value, 2)
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting a range, you need the `SET` command, and you should not `.Select` while setting:

```
rng = Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
```

becomes:

```
Set rng = Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
```

Also, in your rounding you have specified a negative value.

```
cell.Value = Round(cell.Value, -2)
```

Becomes:

```
cell.Value = Round(cell.Value, 2)
```

So the code ends up as so:

```
Sub roundthissheet()
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Value = Round(cell.Value, 2)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may this.

```
Sub RoundValues()
Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address)

    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Value <> "" And IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
            cel.Value = Round(cel.Value2, 2)
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```