# Correct way to precisely round decimals in C#

Tags: c#, rounding

This is my code:

```
    decimal test1 = 190.5m;
    decimal test2 = 191.5m;
    var testResult1 = Math.Round(test1, 0); // =190 It should be 191!!!!
    var testResult2 = Math.Round(test2, 0); // =192 Correct.
```

Is there a way I could get the correct result? Maybe another library instead of System.Math?

Comment: You should describe behavior in edge cases, `var testResult1 = Math.Round(test1, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Comment: Check the [docs for that method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-decimal-system-int32))... "This method uses the default rounding convention of `MidpointRounding.ToEven`."

Comment: *"Check the docs for that method..."* is not something we should ever have to say. You should read the relevant documentation first, as a matter of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. Albeit not what we have grown up with.

Find how you manage to round the way you expect here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

For a bit more reading and background, have a browse through some of the answers here:
[Why does .NET use banker's rounding as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311696/why-does-net-use-bankers-rounding-as-default)