# How to store decimal values in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, decimal

I'm trying to figure out decimal data type of a column in the SQL Server. I need to be able to store values like 15.5, 26.9, 24.7, 9.8, etc

I assigned `decimal(18, 0)` to the column data type but this not allowing me to store these values.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 537):

`DECIMAL(18,0)` will allow 0 digits after the decimal point.

Use something like `DECIMAL(18,4)` instead that should do just fine!

That gives you a **total of 18 digits**, 4 of which after the decimal point (and 14 before the decimal point).

Comment: @marc_s, Is there anyway to store a value "4.5" where the column datatype is decimal(4,2)? When I insert the value, it is getting modified to "4.50"

Comment: @ArunkumarTK: `decimal(4,2)` allows 2 digits before and 2 digits after the decimal point. "4.5" can be stored no problem - and numerically, "4.5" and "4.50" are **identical**

Comment: But in my case "4.5" and "4.50" are all different. Should I use varchar instead?

Comment: @ArunkumarTK: ***WHY*** should those be different?? Both are "four and a half" - the value **IS THE SAME**.And ***NO*** don't use a `varchar` to store a decimal value !!

Comment: @marc_s in my case I am going to store product version where 4.5 and 4.50 are different

Comment: I know this is an old discussion but wouldn't that be '4.05' and '4.5' in that case @ArunkumarTK.

Comment: @ArunkumarTK it definitely sounds like you should be storing varchar if you need exact control over characters etc. But beware if you try to do any math with varchars.

Comment: `DECIMAL(19, 4)` **is a popular choice** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224462/storing-money-in-a-decimal-column-what-precision-and-scale) also check [here](http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat) World Currency Formats  to decide how many decimal places to use , hope helps.

Comment: Yeah, why is 18 so popular (e.g. the default (18,0)) when both 18 and 19 [use 9 bytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql)?

Comment: The last sentence from ya answer is the best and actually the only answer that i was lookin fo !! cheers

Comment: For a little perspective `DECIMAL(18,0)` is in the hundred quadrillion range.

Comment: @xr280xr 18 is used simply because that's the default. If I simply define the column as `DECIMAL`, it's changed to `DECIMAL(18,0) automatically

Answer (score 145):

You should use is as follows:

```
DECIMAL(m,a)
```

`m` is the number of total digits your decimal can have.

`a` is the max number of digits you can have after the decimal point.

Comment: It is usually denoted as DECIMAL (p,s) where p stands for precision (maximum allowed digits in a number) and s stands for scale (maximum allowed digits after the decimal point).

Answer (score 48):

The settings for `Decimal` are its precision and scale or in normal language, how many digits can a number have and how many digits do you want to have to the right of the decimal point.

So if you put `PI` into a `Decimal(18,0)` it will be recorded as `3`?

If you put `PI` into a `Decimal(18,2)` it will be recorded as `3.14`?

If you put `PI` into `Decimal(18,10)` be recorded as `3.1415926535`.

Answer (score 39):

For most of the time, I use decimal(9,2) which takes the least storage (5 bytes) in sql decimal type.

---

Precision =>     Storage bytes

- 1 - 9         => 5
- 10-19         => 9
- 20-28         => 13
- 29-38         => 17

---

It can store from 0 up to 9 999 999.99 (7 digit infront + 2 digit behind decimal point = total 9 digit), which is big enough for most of the values.

Answer (score 12):

You can try this

```
decimal(18,1)
```

The length of numbers should be totally 18. The length of numbers after the decimal point should be 1 only and not more than that.

Answer (score 7):

In MySQL DB `decimal(4,2)` allows entering only a total of 4 digits. As you see in `decimal(4,2)`, it means you can enter a total of 4 digits out of which two digits are meant for keeping after the decimal point.

So, if you enter 100.0 in MySQL database, it will show an error like "Out of Range Value for column".

So, you can enter in this range only: from 00.00 to 99.99.

Comment: Why this is relevant while the question specified clearly Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are right. Assuming your examples reflect the full range of possibilities what you want is `DECIMAL(3, 1)`. Or, `DECIMAL(14, 1)` will allow a total of 14 digits. It's your job to think about what's enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
request.input("name", sql.Decimal, 155.33)              // decimal(18, 0)
request.input("name", sql.Decimal(10), 155.33)          // decimal(10, 0)
request.input("name", sql.Decimal(10, 2), 155.33)       // decimal(10, 2)
```