# How to store decimal in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've tried using DECIMAL with (2,2) but it won't let me use this.

I simply want to store a number, for example 7.50 or 10.50.  I need to keep both numbers after the decimal though but when I refresh the database it resets the values to 0.99.  Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store decimal values in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813287/how-to-store-decimal-values-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The first parameter of the `DECIMAL` declaration is the *total* digits.  You probably want to use `DECIMAL (4, 2)`.  This allows for up to two digits before the decimal and two after.

Documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html

Answer (score 25):

The syntax is DECIMAL(M,D)

M - total length

D - digits right of the decimal point

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.6 are as follows:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`cost` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL);
```

This will make the cost column hold a total of 10 digits, 8 before and 2 after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `salary` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`salary` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`DECIMAL(10,2)` indicates that `salary` will hold a total of 10 digits out of which 2 will be after the decimal.

i.e.

8 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal.

Answer (score 0):

[From mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html):

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> - M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of
>   1 to 65.
> - D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

**NB:- M is total no. of digits before decimal point + total no. of digits after decimal point.**

In your case, `7.50` has a total no of 3 digits and `10.50` has a total no of 4 digits. But the declared maximum no. of digits for the column is 2 so it can store a maximum of two digits value. You cannot even store 1 because it's 1.00 i.e. total 3 digits. So the maximum allowed 2 digit value in the column is `.99`.

If you want to store xx.xx then you have to declare (4, 2) where 4 is M and 2 is D.

If you want to store any number at maximum allowed size of mysql then you can declare a column with (65, 30).

*Maximum no. of digits before decimal point = M - D*

Answer (score -5):

Change your field from INT to FLOAT