# How to store dynamic decimal in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

I need to insert a **dynamic decimal** in mysql. Meaning it could be 7.5 or 33.5 or 150.5.
The final value is a percentage based on sales. I found this answer on stack: [How to store decimal in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629759/how-to-store-decimal-in-mysql) but it does not help me with my question.

Is there a simple way to store these examples?

3.5
or
47.5
or
246.5

If I use varchar the decimal does not show up. If I use the code form the answer above the decimal is off.  Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Actually I think its my code. I can't seem to get the decimal to be in the right place. I am trying to get 30% of a random number. This code is not working right below

```
<?
$randomMade = 40;
$TotalMade = (30/$randomMade) * 100;
$TotalMade = round($TotalMade);
echo $TotalMade; // Comes out as 75 - But it should be 7.5 

?>
```

UPDATE: Found percentage issue:

```
$TotalMade = (30*$randomMade) / 100; I had the math wrong. :(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `decimal(5,2)` if you want to store up to three digits to the left of the decimal.

You can adjust the "5" for larger values.

But, you can just store it as a floating point number, and then use `format()` to create a string:

```
select format(123.5, 1)
```

Produces . . .

```
 123.5
```

EDIT:

In php, try:

```
$TotalMade = round($TotalMade, 1);
```

The second argument is the precision.

Comment: I think its an issue with my php code and not squeal. Please see the edit above and let me know if I am right on this assessment.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried the update edit to PHP but it still comes out as 75  and not 7.5

Comment: @PapaDeBeau . . . Do you intend `3/40`?  Because `(30/40)*100` is 75.

Comment: oh man. I meant 30%. So would I use that formula then?  -  $TotalMade = (.30/$randomMade) * 100;  In short I need to get 30% of a number.

Comment: The Answer: $TotalMade = (30*$randomMade) / 100;