# MySql correct data type for decimal numbers

Tags: mysql

In my project I have some values to store into database. Those values are numbers like this: -1.05697877e+01,  1.42707291e+00 ,    -4.32023820e-03  ,  4.53455585e-04 , -9.75e-8, etc...

what is the correct "data" Type to be used as table atribute?

thank you

Comment: May this helpful for you, You can read this! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629759/how-to-store-decimal-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Based on the numbers you've given, Float should work.  If you need more precision consider Double.  More info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html) .