# how to store decimal value in mysql which datatype

Tags: mysql

how to store decimal value in MySQL

i have below data like this

column 1

0.000000
and
column 2

244.225601

how to store it into MySQL

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629759/how-to-store-decimal-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use DECIMAL data type to store decimal values. This may help you. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-decimal/