# Inserting record with decimal field - cuts all decimals

Tags: c#, sql, decimal, rounding

I am inserting a simple object into a database, using Linq2Sql (yes, yes, I will change to EF someday soon).

This object has a decimal value. When I debug, I can see the value of price is 6.8 .

However, when I insert into the database, the value is 7. The datatype of the field is `decimal(18, 0)` .

If it helps, I think it mgiht be because I am on a Danish computer, and the rounding char is "," and not ".".

**My inserting code**:

```
var order = new PlacedOrder()
{
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
    UserId = userid,
    PaymentInfo = paymentInfoId,
    ShippingInfo = shippingInfoId,
    OrderState =orderState.ToString(),
    PaymentMethod = paymentMethod.ToString(),
    Email = email,
    Phone = phone,
    PdfFilePath = pdfPath,
    Price = price,
    PriceVat = vat
};

db.PlacedOrders.InsertOnSubmit(order);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store decimal values in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813287/how-to-store-decimal-values-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the datatype from `decimal(18, 0)`  to `decimal(18, 2)` to store values upto 2 decimal places, or [`decimal(n,m)'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for n precisions with m decimal points.

Because currently datatype is `decimal(18, 0)` , the decimal values are not stored in DB.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem! I will award, IF it doesn't get closed within the next 4 minutes because of duplicate ;-)