# Issues with decimal digits in sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm adding float data in my sql table, but even though I'm adding the value 201.95, the table shows 201.949996... (a lot of decimal digits). Is there any way to handle this ?, since I only want two digits as decimal numbers.

Comment: what database system? what is the data type?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server. I'm using with C# WinForms application.

Comment: what's the data type of the column?

Comment: The datatype is float

Comment: are you able to change that? float is an approximation.

Comment: Which data type do you suggest ?. I only have to use two decimal digits.

Comment: I would use the `money` datatype

Comment: `decimal` or `numeric`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. It was a basic data type problem.

Comment: are you sure you're adding 201.95? you just type it in a text field and the n save it to a database? what's the value of the variable prior to be sent to SQL when you debug?

Answer (score 2):

You may have to re-create the table with the column using `DECIMAL(x, 2)` as data-type.

Where x is any value defined in below article.

[Decimal and Numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx/)

Answer (score 0):

Good to use Decimal or numeric(18,2) (18 is total length and 2 for decimal value)
check this

```
declare @temp float = '201.9500011'
select @temp

declare @temp1 numeric(18,2) = '201.9500011'
select @temp1
```

[How to store decimal values in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813287/how-to-store-decimal-values-in-sql-server)