# SQL Decimal trailing zeros into integer part

Tags: sql, vba, decimal, recordset

I have something like this...

```
Set rs = ....
rs.Addnew
...
rs.price = 48 --->the type of price field in SQL is DECIMAL(18,4)
...
rs.Update
```

Just after the update I look at the new row in SQL and in the `price` column the value now is 480000.0000.

Why is it adding 4 zeroes in the integer part?

Comment: You told it (or perhaps the default is) to use four decimal places. Possibly useful: [How to store decimal values in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/813297/1115360)

Comment: Does not really makes sense to me. Are you sure you have '48' and not anything else?
What happens if you create a recordset on the database?
What database are you using?

Comment: This sounds like a conflict of regional settings concerning decimal separator (comma versus point). What is the decimal separator character in your locale?