# What is the best method of handling currency/money?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I'm working on a very basic shopping cart system.

I have a table `items` that has a column `price` of type `integer`.

I'm having trouble displaying the price value in my views for prices that include both Euros and cents. Am I missing something obvious as far as handling currency in the Rails framework is concerned?

Comment: if someone uses sql, then `DECIMAL(19, 4)` **is a popular choice** check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224462/storing-money-in-a-decimal-column-what-precision-and-scale) also check [here](http://www.thefinancials.com/Default.aspx?SubSectionID=curformat) World Currency Formats  to decide how many decimal places to use , hope helps.

Answer (score 525, accepted):

You'll probably want to use a `DECIMAL` type in your database. In your migration, do something like this:

```
# precision is the total number of digits
# scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

In Rails, the `:decimal` type is returned as `BigDecimal`, which is great for price calculation.

If you insist on using integers, you will have to manually convert to and from `BigDecimal`s everywhere, which will probably just become a pain.

As pointed out by mcl, to print the price, use:

```
number_to_currency(price, :unit => "€")
#=> €1,234.01
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice neutrino and molf! I have one follow up question - how can I display my prices with the accuracy of two decimal places using BigDecimal? Currently the `item.price` is returning "12.5" instead of "12.50" ...

Comment: Use number_to_currency helper, more info at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#M001969

Comment: Actually, it's much safer and easier to use an integer in combination with acts_as_dollars. Have you ever been bitten by floating-point comparison? If not, don't make this your first experience. :) With acts_as_dollars, you put stuff in in 12.34 format, it's stored as 1234, and it comes out as 12.34.

Comment: There is also a Money gem, the Money class which can be stored as a text column using serialized or composed_of

Comment: @Sarah Mei: BigDecimals + decimal column format avoids precisely that.

Comment: I would seriously use the Money gem that Ken Mayer suggested below. Even if it's a little more than what you need now, it sets you up for future ability. It just feels right, too.

Comment: It's important not to just copy this answer blindly - *precision 8, scale 2* gives you a maximum value of **999,999.99**. If you need a number greater than a million then increase the precision!

Comment: It's also important to not just blindly use a scale of 2 if you're handling different currencies – some north-african and arab currencies like the Omani Rial or the Tunisian Dinar have a scale of 3, so *precision 8 scale 3* is more appropriate there.

Comment: In my experience BigDecimal becomes a huge pain, when you do a lot arithmetics. The number of used significant digits shoots up, and it becomes incredibly slow (I read somewhere the performance is O(n) where n = number of digits). A simple `BigDecimal('12.34') * BigDecimal('1.19').power(5) / BigDecimal(3)` results in a BigD with 45 significant digits uses. To avoid this, you'd have to write `BigDecimal('12.34').mult(BigDecimal('1.19').power(5), 10).div(BigDecimal(3), 10)`

Comment: Also, 8.62 is temporarily "8.619999999999999" until it actually gets saved in the db which could fail regex validations.

Comment: It's much safer to use Integers to store. Check out RubyMoney Gem: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails

Comment: If you're adding the precision and scale at the model generation step, you have to wrap the parameter in quotes! **Wrong:** `rails g model Item price:decimal{8,2}`. **Correct:** `rails g model Item 'price:decimal{8,2}'`. This has been fixed in the [Rails usage documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12642/files). If you don't quote it, your migration file will look like: `t.decimal8 :price,  t.decimal2 :price` and cause errors.

Comment: Know your type conversions. If you do any kind of computation, you have to make sure there isn't an implicit conversion to Float (e.g. BigDecimal * Float => Float). I end up doing a lot of "0.05.to_d" in my code to make sure that I'm working in an all BigDecimal world.

Answer (score 123):

Here's a fine, simple approach that leverages `composed_of` (part of ActiveRecord, using the ValueObject pattern) and the Money gem

You'll need

- The [Money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) (version 4.1.0)
- A model, for example `Product`
- An `integer` column in your model (and database), for example `:price`

Write this in your `product.rb` file:

```
class Product > ActiveRecord::Base

  composed_of :price,
              :class_name => 'Money',
              :mapping => %w(price cents),
              :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }
  # ...
```

What you'll get:

- Without any extra changes, all of your forms will show dollars and cents, but the internal representation is still just cents. The forms will accept values like "$12,034.95" and convert it for you. There's no need to add extra handlers or attributes to your model, or helpers in your view.
- `product.price = "$12.00"` automatically converts to the Money class
- `product.price.to_s` displays a decimal formatted number ("1234.00")
- `product.price.format` displays a properly formatted string for the currency
- If you need to send cents (to a payment gateway that wants pennies), `product.price.cents.to_s`
- Currency conversion for free

Comment: How can I hold a balance in a currency other than USD using this approach?

Comment: I love this approach. But please note: make sure your migration for 'price' in this example doesn't allow nulls and defaults to 0 lest you go insane trying to figure out why this doesn't work.

Comment: +1 if you have to support multiple currencies/pricing strategies then the money gem is priceless :)

Comment: I found the [money_column gem](https://github.com/tobi/money_column)  (extracted from Shopify) to be very straight forward to use...easier than the money gem, if you don't need currency conversion.

Comment: It should be noted for all those using the Money gem that the Rails core team is discussing deprecating and removing "composed_of" from the framework. I suspect the gem will be updated to handle this if it happens, but if you are looking at Rails 4.0 you should be aware of this possibility

Comment: Regarding @PeerAllan's comment about the removal of `composed_of` [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/about-the-composed_of-removal/) is more detail on that as well as an alternative implementation.

Comment: Also, this is really reasy using the [rails-money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem.

Comment: The money-rails gem works just fine with Rails 4.1.4, and without using composed_of in the model. Now using Money 6.x.

Comment: rails 5 now has an attributes api so you can handle things more fluently now especially types like money

Answer (score 28):

Common practice for handling currency is to use decimal type.
Here is a simple example from "Agile Web Development with Rails"

```
add_column :products, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

This will allow you to handle prices from -999,999.99 to 999,999.99
You may also want to include a validation in your items like

```
def validate 
  errors.add(:price, "should be at least 0.01") if price.nil? || price < 0.01 
end
```

to sanity-check your values.

Comment: This solution also enables you to use SQL sum and friends.

Comment: Could you possibly do:

validates :price, :presence => true, :numericality => {  :greater_than => 0 }

Answer (score 22):

Just a little update and a cohesion of all the answers for some aspiring juniors/beginners in RoR development that will surely come here for some explanations.

#### Working with money

Use `:decimal` to store money in the DB, as @molf suggested (and what my company uses as a golden standard when working with money).

```
# precision is the total number of digits
# scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
```

Few points:

- `:decimal` is going to be used as `BigDecimal` which solves a lot of issues.
- `precision` and `scale` should be adjusted, depending on what you are representing

  - If you work with receiving and sending payments, `precision: 8` and `scale: 2` gives you `999,999.99` as the highest amount, which is fine in 90% of cases.
  - If you need to represent the value of a property or a rare car, you should use a higher `precision`.
  - If you work with coordinates (longitude and latitude), you will surely need a higher `scale`.

#### How to generate a migration

To generate the migration with the above content, run in terminal:

```
bin/rails g migration AddPriceToItems price:decimal{8-2}
```

or

```
bin/rails g migration AddPriceToItems 'price:decimal{5,2}'
```

as explained in this [blog](http://mitrev.net/rails/2015/04/19/rails-migration-generator-specifying-precision-and-scale/) post.

#### Currency formatting

[KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) the extra libraries goodbye and use built-in helpers. Use `number_to_currency` as @molf and @facundofarias suggested.

To play with `number_to_currency` helper in Rails console, send a call to the `ActiveSupport`'s `NumberHelper` class in order to access the helper.

For example:

```
ActiveSupport::NumberHelper.number_to_currency(2_500_000.61, unit: '€', precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '', format: "%n%u")
```

gives the following output

```
2500000,61€
```

Check the other `options` of [number_to_currency](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) helper.

#### Where to put it

You can put it in an application helper and use it inside views for any amount.

```
module ApplicationHelper    
  def format_currency(amount)
    number_to_currency(amount, unit: '€', precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '', format: "%n%u")
  end
end
```

Or you can put it in the `Item` model as an instance method, and call it where you need to format the price (in views or helpers).

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def format_price
    number_to_currency(price, unit: '€', precision: 2, separator: ',', delimiter: '', format: "%n%u")
  end
end
```

And, an example how I use the `number_to_currency` inside a contrroler  (notice the `negative_format` option, used to represent refunds)

```
def refund_information
  amount_formatted = 
    ActionController::Base.helpers.number_to_currency(@refund.amount, negative_format: '(%u%n)')
  {
    # ...
    amount_formatted: amount_formatted,
    # ...
  }
end
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using Postgres (and since we're in 2017 now) you might want to give their `:money` column type a try.

```
add_column :products, :price, :money, default: 0
```

Comment: Internet seems very wary of this approach. Aka folks saying "Whatever you do, DONT use the postgres money type" - [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

You can go [down the rabbit hole here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726535/which-datatype-should-be-used-for-currency), but to save yoy time none of these half dozen  answers provide a confident yes to using it and all suggest alternative approaches.

Answer (score 9):

Use [money-rails gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails). It nicely handles money and currencies in your model and also has a bunch of helpers to format your prices.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this.  Generally, I handle money by storing it as cents (integer) and using a gem like acts-as-money or money (money-rails) to handle the data in-memory.  Handling it in integers prevents those nasty rounding errors. 
E.g. 0.2 * 3 => 0.6000000000000001
This, of course, only works if you don't need to handle fractions of a cent.

Comment: This is very nice if you are using rails.  Drop it in and don't worry about the issues with a decimal column.  If you use this with a view, this answer may be helpful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898947/rails-number-field-alternative-for-decimal-values

Answer (score 5):

Using [Virtual Attributes (Link to revised(paid) Railscast)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised) you can store your price_in_cents in an integer column and add a virtual attribute price_in_dollars in your product model as a getter and setter.

```
# Add a price_in_cents integer column
$ rails g migration add_price_in_cents_to_products price_in_cents:integer

# Use virtual attributes in your Product model
# app/models/product.rb

def price_in_dollars
  price_in_cents.to_d/100 if price_in_cents
end

def price_in_dollars=(dollars)
  self.price_in_cents = dollars.to_d*100 if dollars.present?
end
```

Source: [RailsCasts #016: **Virtual Attributes**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised): *Virtual attributes are a clean way to add form fields that do not map directly to the database. Here I show how to handle validations, associations, and more.*

Comment: this leaves 200.0 one digit

Answer (score 3):

Definitely [integers](http://www.setfiremedia.com/blog/7-top-tips-for-coding-with-currency).

And even though BigDecimal technically exists `1.5` will still give you a pure Float in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

My underlying APIs were all using cents to represent money, and I didn't want to change that. Nor was I working with large amounts of money. So I just put this in a helper method:

```
sprintf("%03d", amount).insert(-3, ".")
```

That converts the integer to a string with at least three digits (adding leading zeroes if necessary), then inserts a decimal point before the last two digits, never using a `Float`. From there you can add whatever currency symbols are appropriate for your use case.

It's *definitely* quick and dirty, but sometimes that's just fine!

Comment: Can't believe nobody upvoted you. This was the only thing that worked to get my Money object nicely into a form such that an API can take it. (Decimal)

Answer (score 2):

If someone is using Sequel the migration would look something like:

```
add_column :products, :price, "decimal(8,2)"
```

somehow Sequel ignores :precision and :scale

(Sequel Version: sequel (3.39.0, 3.38.0))

Answer (score 2):

I am using it on this way:

```
number_to_currency(amount, unit: '€', precision: 2, format: "%u %n")
```

Of course that the currency symbol, precision, format and so on depends on each currency.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some options to `number_to_currency` (a standard Rails 4 view helper):

```
number_to_currency(12.0, :precision => 2)
# => "$12.00"
```

As posted by [Dylan Markow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968624/737275)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple code for Ruby & Rails**

```
<%= number_to_currency(1234567890.50) %>

OUT PUT => $1,234,567,890.50
```