# Rails 101 | validates_currency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've searched high and low, but I could not find a solution, to what I think seems like a very common task.

In a form I want to have a text input that accepts currency strings (i.e. $1,000,000 or 1000 or $12.12 and in an ideal world even 1 million)

In the database I want to keep the value as a integer.

What is the best way to (a) validate that the input is a valid currency string, (b) when displaying the form, to display it formatted.

For date, i found the a great gem: [validates_timeliness](http://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness),  which allows :

```
validates_date :my_date, :allow_blank => true
```

I would love to find a similar syntax for currency.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to store 12.12 as an integer?

Comment: I have should have been more clear, currently I store my currency in the db as cents.  But I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: Checkout this similar post on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money

Comment: Thanks Dave, I saw that, but I did not see where it handled converting the Currency string to a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`rails_money`](http://github.com/jerrett/rails_money). I think it does everything you need, including handling $ in the input fields and storing the value in cents. In fact, you just create your column as `price_in_cents`, and it does the rest.