# assert_equal says <0.15> expected but was <0.15>, but only if the method computes 0.15 in a certain way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, assert

So for this model method:

```
def tax_rate
  tax_rate = 0.0
  tax_rate += STATE_TAX if state_taxable?  #STATE_TAX = 0.1
  tax_rate += IMPORT_TAX if imported?      #IMPORT_TAX = 0.05
  tax_rate
end
```

This test fails:

```
@item.update_attributes({:state_taxable => true,
                         :imported => true,
                         :price => 32.19})
assert_equal 0.15, @item.tax_rate
```

I get this error:

```
<0.15> expected but was <0.15>.
```

However, this test will pass:

```
@item.update_attributes({:state_taxable => true,
                         :imported => false,
                         :price => 14.99})
assert_equal 0.1, @item.tax_rate
```

So I get the error when tax_rate does 0.0 + 0.1 + 0.05, but not when it does 0.0 + 0.1, or 0.0 + 0.05.  Both 0.15s are Floats, so I don't see what could be causing this.  I've spent too long mulling over this, hopefully someone can point out what the culprit is.  Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, you should store such things as a integer numbers (in cents).

Comment: Good point.  I'll go that route, thanks.  Still an odd assertion failure to me though.

Comment: You can use assert_in_delta for assertion.

Answer (score 8):

Floating-point numbers can't be represented exactly; what you need to do is use `assert_in_delta` to check you're within a specified range.

Something like `assert_in_delta 0.15, @item.tax_rate, 0.001` should do it: it'll check you're within 0.001 of the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error many times and it's been because they were **different classes**.

Try

```
assert_equal 0.15.class, @item.tax_rate.class
```

And I am sure it will say something like

```
<float> expected but was <double>.
```

If you do

```
assert_equal 0.15.to_float, @item.tax_rate.to_float
```

It'll probably pass

Answer (score 0):

`0.1`, along with other numbers, [cannot be represented exactly](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) in floating-point arithmetics. Hence, you should use something like (I'm no Ruby guy):

```
assert_true abs(0.15 - @item.tax_rate) < 0.0001
```

And generally speaking, you shouldn't really be using floats for money/currency: there are a lot of really nasty subtle issues that will lose money between the cracks. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money).

Comment: But tax_rate is still returning 0.15, not 0.149999 or something similar, so why is it causing this problem?  Any suggestions on a way I could do it?

Comment: It may well be 0.14999999999999998 or 0.15000000000000002; those bits at the end get rounded off normally on display, but they're still there in the IEEE representation. Don't compare floating-point numbers (unless you **really** know what you're doing).