# Ruby on Rails: how do I format money for my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, currency

This is what I have so far.

how do I ensure that i'll have two decimals? and that it rounds correctly?

```
$<%=h sale_item.value %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think this covers it: [What is the best method of handling currency/money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money).

Comment: Just for reference: I googled "ruby currency" ...