# Ruby on Rails - Validate a Cost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

What is the best way to validate a cost/price input by a user, validation rules below:

- Examples of formats allowed .23, .2, 1.23, 0.25, 5, 6.3 (maximum of two digits after decimal point)
- Minimum value of 0.01
- Maximum value of 9.99

Comment: What behave do you want if a user enters 4.555 ? Fail? or trim the extra 5?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

#### Check the price and verify the format

```
#rails 3    
validates :price, :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :less_than => 10}

#rails 2
validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 10    
validates_format_of :price, :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/
```

Comment: That's cool that in rails3 you can validate as both the original string and as a number. However, I can't quite see why you're using the ?: assertion here. Surely the ? after the decimal part takes care of the "it's optional" thing?

Comment: If anything you'd want a look-behind assertion there so that 1. (decimal point with no following digits) is invalid? Perhaps I'm just not seeing it :)

Comment: Take care when you use `:greater_than => 0`. If the database field is for example a decimal with a precision of 2, the validation will still allow a value of 0.00001, which will be saved in the table as 0.

Comment: Indeed, you should not use `:greater_than => 0` for @Majiy's above mentioned reason, rather use `:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01`.

Comment: I think you both are missing the fact that the regex will also catch stuff like 0.00001

Comment: This works well, and returns `nil` for more than 2 decimal places: `/\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/`

Comment: I use :with => /^\d+??(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/ } then display error:  SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

Comment: Thanks....Works for me this:  :format => { :with => /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0, :less_than => 10}

Comment: I did some testing and I can't see an advantage of using the lookahead over a normal group like  `/\A\d+(\.\d{0,2})?\z/`. Is there an edge case I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

For client side validations you can use a jQuery plugin like [this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) that allows you to define different valid formats for a given input.

For server side validations and according to this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money) maybe you should use a `decimal` column for `price` in which you can define values for `precision` and `scale`, `scale` solves the two digits after decimal point restriction.

Then to validate the numericality, minimum and maximum value you can use the next validation method:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 10
```

Comment: SQLite 3 ignores the precision and scale arguments and so this will not stop user entering 4.555

Comment: You should not use `:greater_than => 0` for the reason @Majiy mentioned, rather use `:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01`.

Answer (score 2):

You can build custom validations.Lets say, for example the second case:

```
validate :price_has_to_be_greater_than_minimum

def price_has_to_be_greater_than_minimum
  errors.add(:price, "price has to be greater than 0.01") if
  !price.blank? and price > 0.01
end
```

More on this, in the Rails Guides, [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods).

Comment: There is no reason to write a custom validation when Rails provides one out-of-the-box for this: `validates :price, :numericality => { :greater_than => 0.01, :allow_blank => true }`.  Same with the first validation--you are validating against a Regexp, which Rails provides already using `validates :price, :format => ...`