# Unable to validate data for a lower limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to use

```
validates :price, numerically: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
```

to force a price to be greater than 0.01. However, no matter what number I put in, 0.001 or even 0, as long as its numerical, it passes the test. Can anyone tell me why and how can I revise it?

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173530/ruby-on-rails-validate-a-cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numericality` instead of `numerically`