# Formatting a float to a minimum number of decimal places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm storing a decimal in rails and I need to have it display as a currency as such:

```
11.1230 => "$11.123"
11.1000 => "$11.10"
11.0100 => "$11.01"
11.1234 => "$11.1234"
```

Any easy way to do this?

Comment: I think your rules might need to be clarified. Is it "at least two decimal places, but more if necessary"?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: Looks like this is Rails 3 specific, as Rails 2's `number_with_precision` method doesn't include the `strip_insignificant_zeros` option:**

You can pass some options to `number_to_currency` (a standard Rails helper):

```
number_to_currency(11.1230, :precision => 10, :strip_insignificant_zeros => true)
# => "$11.123"
```

You need to provide a precision in order for the `strip_insignificant_zeros` option to work, though, otherwise the underlying `number_with_precision` method never gets called.

Comment: I actually get $11.1230000000 when I run that example

Comment: @dmarkow I don't see the `strip_insignificant_zeros` option in [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency).

Comment: @Jake, you need to lower the `:precision` if you want less zeroes. Those 0's are significant digits, so they won't be tossed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: @Phrogz: It's not documented, but if you specify a precision, it passes ALL the options into number_with_precision (which does support the strip_insignificant_zeros option). (at least in Rails 3)

Comment: @Austin: I'm pretty sure he wants to display more than just two decimal places if the number warrants it. I just picked an arbitrary "high" number.

Comment: @Jake: I was doing this on Rails 3; it's probably different for Rails 2 (assuming that's what you're using)

Answer (score 5):

```
def pad_number( number, min_decimals=2 )
  s = "%g" % number
  decimals = (s[/\.(\d+)/,1] || "").length
  s << "." if decimals == 0
  s << "0"*[0,min_decimals-decimals].max
end
puts [ 11.123, 11.1, 11.01, 11.1234, 11 ].map{ |n| pad_number(n) }
#=> 11.123
#=> 11.10
#=> 11.01
#=> 11.1234
#=> 11.00
```

Comment: Actually the only answer to match the op's question. `11.10`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to store as a float, you can use the number_to_currency(value) method in yours views for printing something that looks like $.

Correct me if I'm wrong (as I've rarely dealt with currency) but I think the conventional wisdom is to store dollar values as integers. That way you won't have to deal with funky float math.

Comment: Yes, store the value in cents, or whatever the smallest currency value is, as integers to avoid rounding errors. Then adjust for the desired dollar amount as a last step by dividing by 100 to return it to the normal $0.00 format.

Comment: I think best practice is to use decimal -- there's no rounding issues and less work for displaying. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money

Answer (score -1):

So, convert it to three decimal fraction digits and then remove the final one if and only if it's a zero.

```
s.sub(/0$/, '')
```

Comment: This does not meet the OP's test case of `11.1234 => "11.1234"`