# Rails 3. How to explicitly round a number to two decimal places in the model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3. How do display two decimal places in edit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772859/rails-3-how-do-display-two-decimal-places-in-edit-form)

I know I can use sprintf to limit to two decimal places.

When I redisplay the prices in a form or just in a table, sometimes I get 80, instead of 80.00. Wouldn't be better to just store the price with the two decimal places from the very moment the price is entered in the database? That way, whenever it's displayed, it will ALWAYS show the two decimal places. If so, how?

Comment: This is not a duplicate question - question is how to round in the MODEL not in the view (as in "dupe" question).  In the model you can use round(2) but it won't FORCE two decimal places in a string response.  To force two decimal places use sprintf('%.2f',number) - but this won't round (it just truncates).  Most of the time when working with currency you would want to round then use sprintf on the final output.  Answering here because question is closed to answers, because flagged as dupe.

Comment: Voting to reopen for reason stated by @Eskim0. The model and edit forms are different places and although the core of the answers are similar/the same, the way of implementing differs (e.g. you wouldn't put `value: ...` in the model as could be done in an html form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should try using the `:decimal` type of database field, with the `:scale` set to `2`

To add a decimal column to a new table;

```
create_table :my_table do |t|
  t.decimal :my_column, :scale => 2
end
```

To add a column to an existing table;

```
add_column :my_table, :my_column, :decimal, :scale => 2
```

It is wise to have precisions since some database does not have precision defaults. Such as postgresql:

```
 add_column :my_table, my_column, precision: 30, scale: 2
```

Comment: Used this but it only allows 1 decimal place `change_column :items, :cost, :decimal, :precision => 10, :scale => 2`. weird.

Comment: I enter amounts with 4 decimal places, and it allows them, shouldn't only store 2 decimal places?

Comment: does not work for me without supplying `:precision`, if i put `:scale` only I get 0 for precision.

Answer (score 41):

You can simply use `x.round(2)` when displaying the number - that will always display two decimal places. It's generally recommended to store prices as integers in the backend database  because they are handled better when you need a really high level of precision. In this case though, you can choose to go either way.

Comment: nope - 23.round(2)
=> 23.0

Comment: 23.round(2) is == 23.0.   23.0 and 23.00 are the same thing.

Comment: @Websitescenes yes they are equivalent, but the question references "display" so it seems the real desire is for a consistent number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

Answer (score 21):

If it's a `:float` or `:decimal`, `80` and `80.00` in Ruby are going to be the same thing (as will `80.0000`). The latter isn't "stored" with more decimal places, and trailing zeroes only make sense in the view. You can use `sprintf` like you said, or you can use Rails' handy `number_with_precision` helper:

```
<%= number_with_precision price, :precision => 2 %>
```

Here's [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money) on this topic, by the way. @Matthew Rudy is right about one thing: For money columns you should be using `:decimal`.

If you're *really* committed to not having this in your view, you could use something like [Draper](https://github.com/jcasimir/draper) to apply decorators to your attributes (which will merely move your `number_with_precision` call out of the way and into a new Decorator class), but it's probably overkill in this instance.

Comment: you would need the helper included for this to work in the model.

Answer (score 8):

For this I use the **number_to_currency** formater.  Since I am in the US the defaults work fine for me.

```
<% price = 45.9999 %>
<price><%= number_to_currency(price)%></price>
=> <price>$45.99</price>
```

You can also pass in options if the defaults don't work for you.
Documentation on available options at [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency)

Comment: won't work in the model without including the helper

Comment: This is something I was looking for, but still, it would be better to have price $17, not $17.00, when there are to cents!