# Rails currency with 2 decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following were my HomeController:

```
def index
  @products = Product.public_active
                     .order('random()')
                     .limit(6)
                     .includes(:product_attachments)
                     .includes(:product_reviews)

  @products.each do |product|
    if product.currency != session[:currency]
      if session["currency-convert-#{product.currency}"].to_f == 0.0
        rate = 1.0  
      else
        rate = session["currency-convert-#{session[:currency]}"].to_f / 
               session["currency-convert-#{product.currency}"].to_f
      end
    else
      rate = 1.0
    end

    product.price_with_currency = 300.00
    product.current_currency = session[:currency]
  end
end
```

And here is my View:

```
<div id="product-list">
                <div class="row">
<p class="price"><%= product.price_with_currency %></p>
</div>
</div>
```

The issues is, `price_with_currency` output the result of `300.0` not `300.00`. Why it is so? Thanks!!

Comment: @Albin in view? something like this `<%= product.price_with_currency, :precision => 2 %>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper called: `number_with_precision`

it would look like this:

```
<p class="price"><%= number_with_precision(product.price_with_currency, :precision => 2) %></p>
```

read more here: [Rails 3. How to display two decimal places in edit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772859/rails-3-how-to-display-two-decimal-places-in-edit-form)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [number_to_currency](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency) helper

For eg.

```
<%= number_to_currency(300, :unit => "$ ", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ",") %>

## Output
$ 300.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use either the two:

```
<p class="price"><%= number_with_precision(product.price_with_currency, precision: 2) %></p>
```

OR

```
<p class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price_with_currency, unit: "USD", precision: 2) %></p>
```

if you want currency with it :D like this `USD 3,000.00` #if 3000