# How to round a float in the model so you don't have to round it elsewhere (it is just saved in rounded form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, floating-point, rounding

I was wondering if there was a way to round a number in the model, so that I would not have to round the number to my specified decimal places anywhere else but there.

I looked at these two posts, but neither answered my question:

- [Rails 3. How to explicitly round a number to two decimal places in
  the model? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772436/rails-3-how-to-explicitly-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-the-model)
- [Rails 3. How to display two decimal    places in edit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772859/rails-3-how-to-display-two-decimal-places-in-edit-form)

The first being a supposed duplicate of the second, but in my opinion it is not. Regardless, neither answered my question clearly.

Is there any possible way of rounding **floats** once in the model?

Comment: Try a `:before_validation` hook -- It has been years since I've used Rails but that's what I'd have done if I was in your shoes. Of course the database will still store a float but it will be the rounded value +/- the machine epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

Just using currencies as an example!

- Use a hook (:before_save)
- Write down as many attributes you need inside :round_decimals.

```
# models/Currency.rb
class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :round_decimals

  private

  def round_decimals
    self.spot_rate = self.spot_rate.round(2)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what a good way would be is to overwrite the setter. (in your case, but in general I would use an integer if you have to store rounded floats.)

```
class Xyz < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_float=(value)
    if value.is_a? Float
      super(value.round)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```