# How to generate scaffold for data type with "extra description" in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scaffolding

From [Ruby on Rails: best method of handling currency / money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money), how do you generate a scaffold for the folowing:

```
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

Such as:

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem name:string \
                                 price:decimal {:precision => 8, :scale => 2}
```

Also, what is the correct term for "extra description" for the decimal type?

Working in Rails 3.07, Ruby 1.92

Comment: Please expand on "what is the correct term for 'extra description' for the decimal type".  I simply don't understand what you are asking there.  Please expand with more detail, description, example, etc.

Comment: @Michael: 'extra description' means `{:precision => 8, :scale => 2}`

Comment: as smile-on pointed the Correct scaffold syntax **field_name:decimal{p.s}**

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**In Rails 3.1** and below, the syntax is

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem name:string price:decimal
```

and then manually add the decimal properties to the migration file

```
t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

**In Rails 3.2**, one can specify the decimal properties

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem name price:decimal{8,2}
```

NOTE: If you are running **ZSH**, the syntax requires a hyphen instead of a comma.

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem name price:decimal{8-2}
```

ANOTHER NOTE: If you are using bash under **Mac OS X 10.9** try a dot instead of the comma

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem name price:decimal{8.2}
```

Comment: Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: @Dogweather The documenation is in the Rails 3.2 release notes under the Railties section http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#railties (all three lines of it) As for the Z-shell fix, it was embedded in this issue https://gist.github.com/rails/rails/issues/4602

Comment: The `rails generate scaffold LineItem name price:decimal{8,2}` syntax didn't work for me, and I'm using Rails 3.2.3.

Comment: @mjnissim Is your terminal running the default bash or do you have Z-Shell installed?

Comment: The suggested ZSH workaround doesn't work for me, I have to quote the parameter, i.e. `rails generate scaffold LineItem name "price:decimal{8,2}"`

Comment: @Stefan Thx for sharing. What OS and flavor of ZSH are you running? I just tested my ZSH answer again using OSX Mountain Lion, Rails 4, and Oh My ZSH and it worked correctly.

Comment: @scarver2 ZSH 5.0.2 with [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) on OS X 10.8.4. It expands `foo{1-3}` to `foo1 foo2 foo3`

Comment: This is due to to the [`BRACE_CCL`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) option.

Comment: On OS X Lion using bash I had to use the suggested ZSH syntax.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes here while working on Mavericks with Rails 4, both `decimal{X.Y}` and `decimal{X-Y}` will do the work. Thanks @scarver2 and @BooVeMan!

Answer (score 12):

A few years later, with Rails 4.2 and bash (Linux) the following generator command works without problems:

```
bin/rails generate scaffold LineItem name:string price:decimal{8.2}
```

This will correctly generate the following example migration:

```
class CreateLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :price, precision: 8, scale: 2

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

Almost a year later. Rails 3.2.11. Regular bash shell. Rails scaffold creates mess with syntax *field_name:decimal{p,s}* regardless of [railties official doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#railties).
The confusion lays in simple fact that curly braces are meta-characters in bash (as well as in other shells) and needs to be escaped. See logged [issue 4602](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4602) in scaffold generator repo.

If you using bash then use dot instead of comma as workaround.  
Correct scaffold syntax **field_name:decimal{p.s}**

Comment: +1 decimal{18,2} didn't work for me in Rails4.0 and bash, this was the correct answer.

Comment: same in rails 4, comma didn't work. haven't tried dot, just added the scale / precision manually in the migration... felt more safe to me

Answer (score 3):

New approach:

Create the migration with just add_column, e.g. 
`rails generate migration AddPriceToLineItem price:integer`

Then edit the migration and change it to be how you want it, e.g.

```
add_column :line_items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

Getting the command line exactly right to do this has proved to be a major exercise in frustration and wasted time for me in the past.  I recommend you follow this procedure and move on.

Answer (score 3):

This is the accurate and most simple way to do this under Rails 5.x:

`rails generate scaffold LineItem name price:decimal{'8,2'}`

Pay special attention to the single quotes used when specifying scale and precision.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it:

```
rails generate scaffold LineItem ... amount:decimal ...
```

The `...` are any other fields we need in the scaffold, like `date:date`, `item:string`, `category:references`...

Then I modified the migration to look like:

```
create_table :line_items do |t|
  .
  .
  .
  t.decimal :amount, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

Then

```
rake db:migrate
```

This holds values between -999,999.99 to 999,999.99.

Here is some (marginally) useful reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html