# What do these curly braces mean?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working through a rails tutorial, and came across this line `rails g model product name decimal:{7, 2}`.

What do those curly braces at the end mean? What do they do?

Originally, I thought they force a level of precision with floating point numbers, but that proved to be false. I could make a decimal 10 digits long with a decimal going to the thousandths place.

Comment: Those sets precision of decimals. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560233/how-to-generate-scaffold-for-data-type-with-extra-description-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see for example: 
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html

There it says:

> For clarity’s sake: the precision is the number of significant digits,
>   while the scale is the number of digits that can be stored following
>   the decimal point. For example, the number 123.45 has a precision of 5
>   and a scale of 2. A decimal with a precision of 5 and a scale of 2 can
>   range from -999.99 to 999.99.

Comment: Oh I see. I was looking at precision wrong. Thanks! Ben is the best name btw ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's the decimal field's *precision* (total number of digits) and *scale* (digits after the decimal point).

From `rails g model -h`:

```
For decimal two integers separated by a comma in curly braces will be used
for precision and scale:

    `rails generate model product price:decimal{10,2}`
```

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html):

> The declaration syntax for a `DECIMAL` column is `DECIMAL(M,D)`. The
>   ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:
>
> - `M` is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>     to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)
> - `D` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>     scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than `M`.