# Rails: remove decimal from number_to_currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a float price:

```
number_to_currency(m.price, :locale => 'en_us')
```

I get: `$39.00`

How can I remove `.00`, I want get:

```
$39
```

Comment: And what you wanna get for `$39.99`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails: best method of handling currency / money](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money)

Comment: If you only wants to remove insignificant 0 you can use this option: `number_to_currency(amount, strip_insignificant_zeros: true)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can set the precision to 0 as documented [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) in the Rails API Docs.

```
number_to_currency(m.price, locale: :en, precision: 0)
```

Be aware that your prices will be rounded, anything from $38.50 to $39.49 will be displayed as $39.

*Edit*: Exchanged locale `:en_us` for `:en`, which might be enabled in more apps.

Comment: I'm getting `"en_us" is not a valid locale`

Comment: Try `locale: :en`. Your error message probably relates to `I18n.enforce_available_locales`.

Comment: `number_to_currency(your_number_here, unit: "", separator: ".", delimiter: ",", precision: 0)`

Answer (score 23):

Assuming that you want to skip decimals only in case of 0 cents, how about

```
number_to_currency(m.price, :locale => 'en_us').gsub(/\.00$/, "")
```

Comment: Maybe not what the op was looking for, but this helped me a ton-- thanks!

Comment: I found this is really useful when you want to hide .00 only, but keep any pence if it's available.