# Variable data type and changes to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, types, numbers, type-conversion

I am trying to find out a data type of a certain variable (it is a column in a db in RoR application). I would like to format it as a number with 2 decimals, but I want to first find out if it is a string or an integer.

- How can I find out?
- How can I change it? (And do I need to)
- How do I format it to two decimals, whatever the original is?
- What is the best way to go about this - change it in css? in js? in the variable type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the format of your 2-decimals number, see this post [What is the best method of handling currency/money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money)

The best way to do is to not change it, and register it directly with rails.

If you have to change a string to a 2-decimal number, create a migration with

- add_column `my_decimal_number`
- execute an DB query to update your table from `my_string_number` to `my_decimal_number`
- deletes `my_string_number`

Answer (score 2):

- The data type is specified in the database schema (schema.rb)
- If you want to change it from string -> integer, you have to write a database migration.
- The best way to implement it would probably be in a view helper. (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#view-helpers)