# Rails number_field alternative for decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to accept a decimal value (USD, so 12.24 would be an example) with the number_field method.

```
<div class="controls">
  <%= f.number_field :amount, :class => 'text_field' %>
</div>
```

This only allows me to enter integer values.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can bypass the "only Integers" constraint by adding a Float for the step option:

```
f.number_field :amount, step: 0.5
```

---

**Update:**
Actually you can use the value 'any' for the step, it will accept all floats and integers, and the step will be 1:

```
f.number_field :amount, step: :any
```

---

**Update for prices:**

You can use the rails' helper `number_to_currency` to display a price inside a number_field:

```
f.number_field :amount, value: number_to_currency(f.object.amount.to_f, delimiter: '', unit: ''), step: :any
```

Comment: `:step => 0.01` if you want numbers with 2 decimal digits

Comment: Is this round-off for display only, or also for internal representation?

Comment: @Lori The value displayed is the same as the one submitted with the html form. If you enter `0.33` in a `number_field_tag :amount`, you will receive `params[:amount]` equal to  `0.33`

Answer (score 10):

For price fields you can use this:

```
f.number_field :price, value: @item.price ? '%.2f' % @item.price : nil, min: 0, step: 0.01
```

It works fine even if you allow blank values.

Comment: That worked fine, thanks!
Also, how can we avoid the user put the symbol minus (-)?