# Saving Ruby Decimals in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, decimal

I have a Ruby attribute that I'm trying to save as part of a form that is:

> t.decimal  "fantasy_points", precision: 4, scale: 1

In my form I'm trying to use the input:

```
<%= f.text_field :fantasy_points, :value => number_with_precision(f.object.fantasy_points) %>
```

When use the form I get a success message but no value is saved and I get a 'nil' value in my database. However, I can still save a value manually in the console. I'm new to rails and any help would be great.

Comment: Have you tried `f.number_field`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails number\_field alternative for decimal values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898947/rails-number-field-alternative-for-decimal-values)

Comment: can you please post your controller code