# Rails How to store signed decimals and how to parse a string for numbers in ruby

Tags: ruby, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 questions

I have a rails app that fetches market data  about currencies from an rss feed that returns data in the following format

```
a = ["31.25", "*33.00*", "*+1.75*", "*5.60%*", "33", "33"]
b = ["3.55", "*3.45*", "*-0.10*", "*-2.82%*", "3.5", "3.4"]
```

I need to store this values in a database as decimal data type columns for precision purposes since I'm dealing with money.

The first question is:

I need to convert the above arrays to the following format,

```
 a = [31.25,33.00,1.75,5.60,33,33]

 b = [3.55,3.45,-0.10,2.82,3.5,3.4]
```

And the second question is,

What rails command should I use to create a model for sqlite and postgresql databases with one-column that has capabilities to store signed decimals e.g. +1.75 and -0.10

I've tried

```
rails g model currency dollar:decimal
```

Instead, when I save -0.10 in this model and then query for it using,

```
Currency.last.dollar
```

the following is returned,while I just need it to return -0.10

```
#<BigDecimal:ae244d8,'0.0',9(27)>
```

Comment: For the question,you can use `to_f`.

Comment: a[1].to_f returns 0.00 instead of 33.00

Comment: use `a.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }`

Comment: @zishe .... I've done q=z.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }, then inspected q which returns ["3.55", "3.45", "-0.10", "-2.82", "3.5", "3.4"] that I can just convert to float using q.to_f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

```
a.map{ |x| x.scan(/[\d\.-]+/)[0] }.map(&:to_f)
```

Second:

```
Currency.first.dollar.to_f # => -0.1
```

Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/ruby-on-rails-best-method-of-handling-currency-money) maybe more proper:

```
add_column :currency, :dollar, :decimal, precision: 8, scale: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regexps:

```
f = []
a.each do |i|
  f << i.match(/\-?[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/)[0].to_f
end

puts f
```

If you have a lot of data then use precompired regexp