# Rails Money gem - block users from entering cents/pennies/subunits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, money-rails

I'm using money-rails with my Rails 4 app.

I display my monetized attributes without cents. I'd like users to enter whole dollar/pound amounts only (so instead of 100 being $1, I'd like it to be $100).

In my form, I ask users:

```
        <%= par.input :participation_cost_pennies, label: false, placeholder: 'Whole numbers only', :input_html => {:style => 'width: 250px; margin-top: 20px', class: 'response-project'} %>
```

In my show, I have:

```
   <%= money_without_cents_and_with_symbol @project.scope.participant.participation_cost  %>
```

I'd like to know how to either add .00 to whatever gets entered by the user in the form, or preferably, to make the entered value a dollar amount rather than a cents amount. Does anyone know how to do that?

I have removed cents in my money.rb initialiser:

```
config.default_format = {
     :no_cents_if_whole => nil,
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with money I like to use `DECIMAL` instead of `INTEGERS` in my database.

In your migration, do something like this:

```
add_column :items, :price, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
# precision is the total amount of digits
# scale is the number of digits right of the decimal point
```

In Rails, the `:decimal` type is returned as `BigDecimal`, which is great for price calculation.

If you insist on using integers, you will have to manually convert to and from `BigDecimal`s everywhere.

to print the price, use:

```
number_to_currency(price, :unit => "$")
#=> $1,234.01
```

look at 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1019972/1380867

Comment: Hi, but does BigDecimal block users from entering cents or pennies?

Comment: no the opposite the BigDecimal is a Decimal so it allows you to enter the dot "." that brakes the money into the cents or pennies that is where the `:scale` comes into place *scale is the number of digits right of the decimal point*

Comment: so how do i block people from entering .00? I want them to enter 100 and for it to mean $100

Comment: for **$100**, they would enter **100** and for **$100.50** they would enter **100.50** they dont need to put the dot unless they want to enter cents