# Rails Money not saving properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the Money gem and composed_of as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3843805/4162458

I have an integer column in my database, :discount

product.rb

```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    composed_of :discount_display,
      :class_name => 'Money',
      :mapping => %w(discount cents),
      :converter => Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value) }
```

And in my form:

```
<%= f.number_field :discount_display, class: 'form-control', min: "0" %>
```

However, if I enter 12, it saves in the database as 12 and displays on the form when I refresh as 0.12.

How can I have it so that when you enter "12" it is saved as 1200 in the db and displays properly, as that answers seems to say should happen?

Comment: Take a look at the [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) gem, it handles the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money),

> Represents monetary values as integers, in cents. This avoids floating
>   point rounding errors.

Hence, if you expect collect dollars from the user, then, you need to convert it to cents before saving in DB.  Perhaps, your converter proc should be

```
Proc.new { |value| Money.new(value * 100) }
```

or

```
Proc.new { |value| Money.from_amount(value, "USD") }
```