# A simple approach to currency formatting in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

I spent most part of today trying to figure out how to give my integer fields a currency format and was bombarded with a myriad of different approaches from using Money, Rails-Money gems to using custom helper methods or locales.

> You can achieve this by using the `number_to_currency` method. Say you
>   have the following view:

*view.html.erb*

```
<ul>
    <li><%= client.payment %></li>
</ul>
```

**Assuming the column payments is of type integer, this will print out just that, a number with no formatting. Ex: 5523**

> Now add the number_to_currency method and specify which currency unit
>   you'd like to use (can be any)

```
<ul>
    <li><%= number_to_currency(client.payment, :unit => "$") %></li>
</ul>
```

**Now we get something like this: 5.523.00$**

> The number_to_currency method helper has some options by default, one
>   of those is that it inverts (as opposed to common practice) the usage
>   of comma and period. These can be modified by adding the options
>   :separator and :delimiter and give them the values you'd like as is
>   below.

```
<ul>
    <li><%= number_to_currency(client.payment, :unit => "$", :separator => ".", :delimiter => ",") %></li>
</ul>
```

These are the available options for the number_to_currency method helper ([RubyOnRailsAPI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html)):

```
:locale - Sets the locale to be used for formatting (defaults to current locale).

:precision - Sets the level of precision (defaults to 2).

:unit - Sets the denomination of the currency (defaults to “$”).

:separator - Sets the separator between the units (defaults to “.”).

:delimiter - Sets the thousands delimiter (defaults to “,”).

:format - Sets the format for non-negative numbers (defaults to “%u%n”). Fields are %u for the currency, and %n for the number.

:negative_format - Sets the format for negative numbers (defaults to prepending a hyphen to the formatted number given by :format). Accepts the same fields than :format, except %n is here the absolute value of the number.

:raise - If true, raises InvalidNumberError when the argument is invalid.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best method of handling currency/money?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019939/what-is-the-best-method-of-handling-currency-money)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it a few different ways. Personally I would recommend doing this in a decorator (https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to remove some logic and formatting out of the view.

As mentioned in a prior answer you can use `number_to_currency` and not use other options to get the correct formatting you are looking for. It can take an integer, float, or string.

```
number_to_currency 10000
=> "$10,000.00"
```

Another way is to use `money-rails` (https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) if you want to deal with a `Money` object:

```
money = Money.new(10000)
=> #<Money fractional:10000 currency:USD>

humanized_money_with_symbol money
=> "$10,000.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using it without any options?
  number_to_currency(client.payment)
It should default to $ and has worked fine for me without any options.